# Best way to escape javascript string? (json?)

Tags: c#, .net, javascript, json

Using C# .net I am parsing some data with some partial html/javascript inside it (i dont know who made that decision) and i need to pull a link. The link looks like this

```
http:\/\/fc0.site.net\/fs50\/i\/2009\/name.jpg
```

It came from this which i assume is javascript and looks like json

```
"name":{"id":"589","src":"http:\/\/fc0.site.net\/fs50\/i\/2009\/name.jpg"}
```

But anyways how should i escape the first link so i get 
    http://fc0.site.net/fs50/i/2009/name.jpg

In this case i could just replace '\' with '' since links dont contain \ nor " so i could do that but i am a fan of knowing the right solution and doing things properly. So how might i escape this. After looking at that link for a minute i thought **is that valid**? does java script or json escape / with \? It doesnt seem like it should?

Answer (score 1):

In your case:

```
"name":{"id":"589","src":"http://fc0.site.net/fs50/i/2009/name.jpg"}
```

"/" is a valid escape sequence. However, it is not required that / be escaped. You may escape it if you need to. The reason JSON explicitly allows escaping of slash is because HTML does not allow a string in a  to contain "...

**Update:**

- [Check out this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580647/json-why-are-forward-slashes-escaped)

Comment: I think you misread a part. I already do "" in my C# strings and dont see why you mentioned that. I asked how do i escape the 1st string in C#.

Comment: @acidzombie24: sorry about that. I'll read well next time. Hope my answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Odd, it doesn’t look like any JavaScript/JSON escaping you’d expect. You can have forward slashes in JavaScript strings just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try a regex on the escaped slashes to replace them in the C# code...

```
String url = @"http:\/\/fc0.site.net\/fs50\/i\/2009\/name.jpg";

String pattern = @"\\/";

String cleanUrl = Regex.Replace(url, pattern, "/");
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Not sure Jamie Zawinski would agree

Answer (score 0):

Actually you want to *unescape* the string. Answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334479/json-decoding-in-c).