# How can I connvert a JSON object to a custom C# object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, json

Is there an easy way to populate my C# object with the JSON object passed via AJAX?

This is the JSON object passed to a C# *web method* from the page using *JSON.stringify*:

```json
{
    "user": {
        "name": "asdf",
        "teamname": "b",
        "email": "c",
        "players": ["1", "2"]
    }
}
```

The C# web method that receives the JSON object:

```cs
[WebMethod]
public static void SaveTeam(Object user)
{

}
```

The C# class that represents the object structure of JSON Object passed in to the web method

```cs
public class User
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string teamname { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public Array players { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Would like to add that you can use http://json2csharp.com to generate your c# classes for you. Full disclosure: I did create this site.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191167/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object-list

Comment: As opposed to `json2csharp` there is actually a better tool to generate classes which is https://app.quicktype.io/, gives good customizations to your models.

Answer (score 240, accepted):

A good way to use JSON in C# is with [JSON.NET](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json)

[Quick Starts & API Documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/) from  [JSON.NET - Official site](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) help you work with it.

An example of how to use it:

```
public class User
{
    public User(string json)
    {
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        JToken jUser = jObject["user"];
        name = (string) jUser["name"];
        teamname = (string) jUser["teamname"];
        email = (string) jUser["email"];
        players = jUser["players"].ToArray();
    }

    public string name { get; set; }
    public string teamname { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public Array players { get; set; }
}

// Use
private void Run()
{
    string json = @"{""user"":{""name"":""asdf"",""teamname"":""b"",""email"":""c"",""players"":[""1"",""2""]}}";
    User user = new User(json);

    Console.WriteLine("Name : " + user.name);
    Console.WriteLine("Teamname : " + user.teamname);
    Console.WriteLine("Email : " + user.email);
    Console.WriteLine("Players:");

    foreach (var player in user.players)
        Console.WriteLine(player);
 }
```

Comment: This works like a champ, but what if i have multiple items in my json and i want to make an object list?

Comment: @Djeroen: I see two ways for that. If items are not grouped try to find a way to split the string an repeat the process in a loop. If they are grouped make an object of objects

Answer (score 270):

This one depends on the Newtonsoft NuGet package, which is faster than the default serializer.

if we have a class then we can use the below code:

```
Mycustomclassname oMycustomclassname = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Mycustomclassname>(jsonString);
```

if no class then use dynamic:

```
var oMycustomclassname = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 97):

To keep your options open, if you're using .NET 3.5 or later, here is a wrapped up example you can use straight from the framework using Generics. As others have mentioned, if it's not just simple objects you should really use JSON.net.

```
public static string Serialize<T>(T obj)
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    serializer.WriteObject(ms, obj);
    string retVal = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
    return retVal;
}

public static T Deserialize<T>(string json)
{
    T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json));
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
    obj = (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
    ms.Close();
    return obj;
}
```

You'll need:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
```

Comment: @ChristianPayne ha! Good point, yes these should be wrapped. With hindsight looking at this, just use JSON.NET!

Comment: If DataContractJsonSerializer class is not visible, you have to add a reference to System.Runtime.Serialization by right clicking on the References in the solution, select the .NET tab and select System.Runtime.Serialization

Comment: One scenario where this one breaks. If your JSON object represents properties with single quotes, this function fails. e.g. it was not able to parse {'Subject': 'Emailing: Web User Activity Log11', 'EmbedAsImage': true} but it was able to parse {"Subject": "Emailing: Web User Activity Log11", "EmbedAsImage": true}

Comment: Plus I needed to decorate my simple class with DataContract and DataMember attributes. It won't parse without it.

Comment: Unlike Vishal, a POCO class worked perfectly for me... +1 as this avoids a dependency on JSON.NET.

Answer (score 54):

Given your code sample, you shouldn't need to do anything else.

If you pass that JSON string to your web method, it will automatically parse the JSON string and create a populated User object as the parameter for your SaveTeam method.

Generally though, you can use the `JavascriptSerializer` class as below, or for more flexibility, use any of the various Json frameworks out there (Jayrock JSON is a good one) for easy JSON manipulation.

```
 JavaScriptSerializer jss= new JavaScriptSerializer();
 User user = jss.Deserialize<User>(jsonResponse);
```

Comment: I think you must use an ienumerable type (so in this example List<User>)

Comment: How can we deserialize if it contains sub view model

Comment: For those looking you need to reference the `System.Web.Extensions` assembly and add a `using System.Web.Script.Serialization` to get at the `JavaScriptSerializer`, but once you do, this seems like the cleanest way to deserialize yours `json` strings into c# concrete classes.

Comment: Anyone stumbling on this answer now should be cognizant of this general advice from MS's own documentation on `JavaScriptSerializer`: _For .NET Framework 4.7.2 and later versions, the APIs in the `System.Text.Json` namespace should be used for serialization and deserialization. For earlier versions of .NET Framework, use `Newtonsoft.Json`._

Answer (score 50):

Another *really* simple solution is using the library Newtonsoft.Json:

```
User user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(jsonString);
```

Comment: but if the User object has another JSon data in the property, this will fails...

Comment: @gumuruh I guess i did not understand your statement. If you have a complex object witch properties are another complex objects, they will also be converted, as long your Json String have the data correctly.

Answer (score 38):

The following 2 examples make use of either

1. **JavaScriptSerializer** under **System.Web.Script.Serialization** Or
2. **Json.Decode** under **System.Web.Helpers**

---

**Example 1:** using System.Web.Script.Serialization

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class JsonTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Test()
        {
            var json = "{\"user\":{\"name\":\"asdf\",\"teamname\":\"b\",\"email\":\"c\",\"players\":[\"1\",\"2\"]}}";
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            dynamic jsonObject = serializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(json);

            dynamic x = jsonObject["user"]; // result is Dictionary<string,object> user with fields name, teamname, email and players with their values
            x = jsonObject["user"]["name"]; // result is asdf
            x = jsonObject["user"]["players"]; // result is object[] players with its values
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:** JSON object to Custom C# object

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Linq;

namespace Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class JsonTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestJavaScriptSerializer()
        {
            var json = "{\"user\":{\"name\":\"asdf\",\"teamname\":\"b\",\"email\":\"c\",\"players\":[\"1\",\"2\"]}}";
            User user = new User(json);
            Console.WriteLine("Name : " + user.name);
            Console.WriteLine("Teamname : " + user.teamname);
            Console.WriteLine("Email : " + user.email);
            Console.WriteLine("Players:");
            foreach (var player in user.players)
                Console.WriteLine(player);
        }
    }

    public class User {
        public User(string json) {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var jsonObject = serializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(json);
            name = (string)jsonObject["user"]["name"];
            teamname = (string)jsonObject["user"]["teamname"];
            email = (string)jsonObject["user"]["email"];
            players = jsonObject["user"]["players"];
        }

        public string name { get; set; }
        public string teamname { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public Array players { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

**Example 2:** using System.Web.Helpers

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Web.Helpers;

namespace Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class JsonTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestJsonDecode()
        {
            var json = "{\"user\":{\"name\":\"asdf\",\"teamname\":\"b\",\"email\":\"c\",\"players\":[\"1\",\"2\"]}}";
            dynamic jsonObject = Json.Decode(json);

            dynamic x = jsonObject.user; // result is dynamic json object user with fields name, teamname, email and players with their values
            x = jsonObject.user.name; // result is asdf
            x = jsonObject.user.players; // result is dynamic json array players with its values
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:** JSON object to Custom C# object

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Web.Helpers;
using System.Linq;

namespace Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class JsonTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestJsonDecode()
        {
            var json = "{\"user\":{\"name\":\"asdf\",\"teamname\":\"b\",\"email\":\"c\",\"players\":[\"1\",\"2\"]}}";
            User user = new User(json);
            Console.WriteLine("Name : " + user.name);
            Console.WriteLine("Teamname : " + user.teamname);
            Console.WriteLine("Email : " + user.email);
            Console.WriteLine("Players:");
            foreach (var player in user.players)
                Console.WriteLine(player);
        }
    }

    public class User {
        public User(string json) {
            var jsonObject = Json.Decode(json);
            name = (string)jsonObject.user.name;
            teamname = (string)jsonObject.user.teamname;
            email = (string)jsonObject.user.email;
            players = (DynamicJsonArray) jsonObject.user.players;
        }

        public string name { get; set; }
        public string teamname { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public Array players { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This code requires adding System.Web.Helpers namespace found in,

> %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web
> Pages{VERSION}\Assemblies\System.Web.Helpers.dll

Or

> %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web
> Pages{VERSION}\Assemblies\System.Web.Helpers.dll

Comment: This is a very good answer, but the tricky thing is that with `dynamic` types, you don't get any true type checking.  For example, if your JSON contains `"Name" : "Ahmed"` and you mistype "Name" in your C# code, it's a runtime error (bleh).

Comment: Thanks! Please update the answer to state that for Example 1, you need to reference System.Web.Extensions.dll

Answer (score 8):

```
public static class Utilities
{
    public static T Deserialize<T>(string jsonString)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(jsonString)))
        {    
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
        }
    }
}
```

More information go to following link
http://ishareidea.blogspot.in/2012/05/json-conversion.html

About `DataContractJsonSerializer Class` you can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx).

Answer (score 7):

Using `JavaScriptSerializer()` is less strict than the generic solution offered :

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(string json)
```

That might come handy when passing json to the server that does not match exactly the Object definition you are trying to convert to.

Answer (score 2):

Performance-wise, I found the ServiceStack's serializer a bit faster than then others. It's JsonSerializer class in ServiceStack.Text namespace.

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text

ServiceStack is available through NuGet package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack/

Answer (score 1):

JSON.Net is your best bet but, depending on the shape of the objects and whether there are circular dependencies, you could use JavaScriptSerializer or DataContractSerializer.

Answer (score 1):

The [JSON C# class generator on codeplex](http://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com/) generates classes which work well with NewtonSoftJS.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript Serializer: requires `using System.Web.Script.Serialization;`

```
public class JavaScriptSerializerDeSerializer<T>
{
    private readonly JavaScriptSerializer serializer;

    public JavaScriptSerializerDeSerializer()
    {
        this.serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    }

    public string Serialize(T t)
    {
        return this.serializer.Serialize(t);
    }

    public T Deseralize(string stringObject)
    {
        return this.serializer.Deserialize<T>(stringObject);
    }
}
```

Data Contract Serializer: requires `using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;`
- The generic type T should be serializable [more on Data Contract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752104%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public class JsonSerializerDeserializer<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer;

    public JsonSerializerDeserializer()
    {
        this.jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
    }

    public string Serialize(T t)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            this.jsonSerializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, t);
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
            {
                return sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }

    public T Deserialize(string objectString)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes((objectString))))
        {
            return (T)this.jsonSerializer.ReadObject(ms);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than sending as just an object, create a public class of properties that is accessible and send the data to the Webmethod.

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SaveTeam(useSomeClassHere user)
{
}
```

Use the same parameters names in the Ajax call to send the data.