# deserializing JSON to .net object using NewtonSoft - array

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, json, json.net

```
{
  "albums": [
    {
      "name": "Muse",
      "permalink": "Muse",
      "cover_image_url": "http://image.kazaa.com/images/69/01672812 1569/Yaron_Herman_Trio/Muse/Yaron_Herman_Trio-Muse_1.jpg",
      "id": 93098,
      "artist_nam e": "Yaron Herman Trio"
    },
```

}

How do i get the value of 'name' contained in 'album'?
Please help! Are there any specific ways to do it? Looked through the api and tried but stuck at retrieving the value!

Answer (score 2):

Just Deserialized  your json into your object.

using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<objectType>(jsonString);`

e.g;
you have a class

```
Public class Album
{
public string name {get;set;}
public string permalink {get;set;},
public string cover_image_url {get;set;}
public int id {get;set;}
public string artist_name{get;set}
}
```

another class

```
public class Albums
{
List<Album> albums{get;set;}
}
```

Then just use

```
 var albums=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Albums>(jsonString);
```

Now albums contains the list of album objects so now you can get any value from there.

Comment: Small tip: You can use http://json2csharp.com/ to create c# classes based on a json string

Comment: what about using Jtoken under the Json.NET api?

Comment: @user1781830 If you just want to get a few items from the JSON object then you can use it

Comment: I tried 
JToken token = JObject.Parse(json);

string album = (string)token.SelectToken("albums");
but it don't seem to be working

Comment: @user1781830 have a look here it shows how to do that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749639/deserializing-json-to-net-object-using-newtonsoft-or-linq-to-json-maybe

Comment: but how do i get the name from this piece of code? please help! thanks!

Comment: you can get it like this 
`string name = (string)token.SelectToken("name");`

Comment: @user1781830 Hey, Why didn't you mark it as answer? I think you have got your answer here..? :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your collection variable is declared public.
For example:

```
public class Albums
{
   public List<Album> albums{get;set;}
}
```