# How to convert a complex JSON in JS into a .NET class in Silverlight

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, json, silverlight

I have a Silverlight project which has to interoperate with the current Javascript library to get JSON data using AJAX and the JSON data looks like the following:

```
{"javaClass":"java.util.ArrayList","list":[{"JOB_NUM":"21", "DEADLINE":{"time":1359583200000,"javaClass":"java.sql.Timestamp"}, "javaClass":"JobEntity"}]}
```

In Silverlight, I've created a "bridge" class to convert the JSON data to C# classes. And the main method is as follows:

```
public static T Invoke<T>(string method)
    {
        ScriptObject result = HtmlPage.Window.Eval("$.parseJSON("+method+")") as ScriptObject;
        if (result != null)
        {
            ScriptObject data = result.GetProperty("list") as ScriptObject;
            if (data != null)
                return data.ConvertTo<T>();
        }

        return default(T);
    }
```

Also, I attach the entity POCO class (simplified) here.

```
public class JobEntity
{
    public string JOB_NUM {get; set;}
    public string DEADLINE {get; set;}
}
```

The question is how to convert the timestamp named "DEADLINE" to a date formatted string in C#. I guess it might be something related to the setter accessor in the property of DEADLINE.

By the way I fount it weird that I can't use the ScriptObject's `ConvertTo<string>()` method if the evaluated value is a string itself in Javascript. Namely, I can only parse the string in this way:

```
scriptObject.ToString();  //ConvertTo<string>() will not work.
```

What's the point here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using Newtonsoft.JSON assembly you can parse the json string into a JToken object then find the date property, as with the accepted answer to this question [Deserializing JSON to .NET object using Newtonsoft (or LINQ to JSON maybe?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749639/deserializing-json-to-net-object-using-newtonsoft-or-linq-to-json-maybe)

Comment: Thanks, Tony. That's absolutely a viable option. Nevertheless, I'm just wondering if things will work out with just some small fixes on the current basis, because ConvertTo does the job in most circumstances. Notably, in this scenario, when I use the method, the DEADLINE property turns out to be an "object". I guess there might be some way to parse it manually. On the other hand, using Linq to JSON or something like that might not be that appropriate in my project which means I have to compose a handful of   mapping codes for my entity classes. Anyway, that's definitely a solution. :)