# Programmatically access dynamic json data

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm looking at the feasibility of creating a dynamic JSON service within my app that will link to outlying JSON services and pull in similar data (but it will have different names).  That way, I won't have to create a JSON object / mapping for the 1000's of  services that this will be connecting to.  My thoughts are to create a mapping between the different JSON services and mine using a configuration created with in the app.

I'm able to create a dynamic JSON object from JSON data using this:

```
    private static void Deserialize(string szJsonData)
    {
        dynamic dObj = JObject.Parse(szJsonData);
    }
```

But to access data within that dynamic object, it appears I still need to know the name and access it like this:

```
string name = dObj.name;
```

What would make this feasible is if I could do something like this:

```
string nameMapping = "name";
string name = dObj[nameMapping];
```

Which would allow me to configure a dynamic mapping back to data within my app.

How could this be accomplished?

Comment: you can map the object with de `propertyReflection` check the properties names of the object, and compare with nameMapping it could work

Comment: If using BSON isn't any issue, you can also parse strings to `BsonDocument` and run through its elements like a dictionary and can even use the notation `dObj[nameMapping]` as you specified. `MongoDB.Bson` is a good library for such.

Comment: Don't assign your `JObject` to a  `dynamic` variable.  `JObject` already supports the syntax you want.  `JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(szJsonData);  string name = jObj["name"];`

Comment: Oh wow! You are right! That works! THANKS!

Comment: So duplicate of [How to get property from dynamic JObject programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16097768/3744182) then?