# JObject to anonymous object with unkown type structure | C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, object, json.net

Im trying to **convert a JObject to an object**. 
I have a WEB-API with ASP.NET framework where I get an Request-Object which has a object-property.
**This object-property has a completely unkown structure and can have different properties or child-objects** (this depends on the sending system). My problem is to parse/convert these JObject´s to a object.

The serialization of an anonymous object is super easy, cause the object definition is clear, but how can I do this the other way around?

I have the following controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("insert")]
public IHttpActionResult Insert(RequestObject ro)
{
}
```

This controller receives the following JSON-Body:

```
{
 "SystemName":"S1_K3",
 "MetaInformation":{
  "Prop1":"X1",
  "Prop3": 12,
  "X1":{
   "User":"XYZ",
   "Session":4
  }
 }
}
```

This JSON-Body is defined as a class in my code as the following:

```
public class RequestObject {
 public string SystemName { get; set;}
 public object MetaInformation { get; set;}
}
```

As you can see MetaInformation is from type 'object' so it can be filled up with the informations provided inside the json. But when I receive the object inside my controller, the property MetaInformation is an object of type JObject.
How can I achieve that my object looks like the following:

```
object metaInformation = new{
 Prop1="X1",
 Prop3=12,
 X1=new{
  User="XYZ", 
  Session=4
 }
};
```

Please keep in mind, that I does not know the object structure at runtime.

Thanks to everyone who can help!

Comment: A `JObject` _is_ an object - you just don't know its properties at compile-time. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16097768

Comment: if you can serialize it to some well-known structure like xml or json, there are popular library to parse and deserialize them. You could get a dictionary for instance, or have some predefined options. At _worst_ there is `dynamic` type, but that would be avoided if possible (no compile time check)

Comment: If you need static / strong typed objects, you can have `JsonConverter`s. Otherwise, `dynamic` or `JObject` should be good.

Comment: Is this what you are asking? [How do I use JSON.NET to deserialize into nested/recursive Dictionary and List?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5546142/10263)

Comment: I´ve updated the description, so it should be more understandable now.

Comment: *Anonymous* objects can only be defined at compile time.  So if you don't know the structure beforehand, there is not a way to create one at run time.  That is exactly what [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) is for.  It gives you a way to handle an unknown JSON object at runtime.

Comment: @BrianRogers I´ve no problem with this, but the object is serialized later to be saved in a MongoDB and there it serializes into JValue etc. but there I need the original JSON.

Comment: You need the original JSON of what? The whole RequestObject, or just the MetaInformation?  If the former, then use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` to serialize it.  If the latter and it is a JObject, then use `MetaInformation.ToString()` to get the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem, cause every system could send me other informations I created an 
`IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` property instead of my object. 
So every system can send me their meta informations and the type is clear for serializing and deserializing.