# JSON deserialization into List<string>

Tags: c#, json, rest, asp.net-web-api, deserialization

I guess this is easy, but I am new and cannot find a fast answer to this:

I want to obtain a list of file names (`List<string>`) in a .Net 2.0 desktop app, using WebClient requesting to a WebAPI REST service.

So, I have this code in the desktop app:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
   client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/json";
   var resultString = client.DownloadString("http://localhost:3788/api/file?src=X&dest=Y");
}
```

and a WebAPI action like this in the service:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetFiles([FromUri]string src, [FromUri]string dest)
{
   // some code here
}
```

How would I convert the `resultString`, which is a JSON `String`, to a `List<String>` ?

Do I have to use `JsonDataContractSerializer`?

Comment: Where is the contents of the JSON string?

Comment: I have to make sure I return only the filenames first and not including the entire path, so I have to make some adjustments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this [SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749639/deserializing-json-to-net-object-using-newtonsoft-or-linq-to-json-maybe). The code there outlines what you would do. The key is to reference the `Newtonsoft.Json` namespace (add it from a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json)) and use the `DeserializeObject` generic method. The answer shows other things you can do with results.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will give it a try. So, there are these 2 libs: Newtonsoft.Json and JSON.NET. Any preference? is there something built-in .net?

Comment: @Cristi they are the same.

Comment: Yes, @L.B. is right. The .NET namespace is `Newtonsoft.Json` but it's probably better known as the Json.NET library.

Comment: Oh... this shows you how noob I am :) Thanks. Let's see if I get the expected results

Comment: Yeah, it worked nicely using: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(resultString);