# Unable to edit JSON with C# (NewtonSoft) because I get an error

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to change the JSON from a JSON file so I can run it to get a JSON response, I found the code on this post: [Change values in JSON file (writing files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21695185/change-values-in-json-file-writing-files) can anyone fix this?

Error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in    Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information:
>   Set JArray values with invalid key value: "filter". Int32 array index expected.

JSON:

```
[{
  "tablename" : "table",
  "columns" : "id, name",
  "filter" : "id = 10"
}]
```

Code:

```
string json = File.ReadAllText("file.json");
dynamic jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
jsonObj["filter"] = "id = 20";
string output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
File.WriteAllText("file.json", output);
```

(The JSON is made to talk to a webservice)

Comment: `jsonObj[0]["filter"] = "id = 20";`

Comment: Your JSON is an array, so you must specify an index, even if it's only 1 item long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should be:

```
jsonObj[0]["filter"] = "id = 20";
```

As your JSON is an array. So 0 is the first object in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options but seeing as you deserialize it to a dynamic then you can try the following.

```
var json = File.ReadAllText("file.json");
dynamic jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

jsonObj[0].filter = "id = 20"; //<--CALLING PROPERTY DIRECTLY via DynamicObject

var output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
File.WriteAllText("file.json", output);
```

The JSON data shown is a JSON array so you need to use index to get elements of the array.

You could also create a class to hold the deserialized data

```
public class Model
{
    public string tablename { get; set; }
    public string columns { get; set; }
    public string filter { get; set; }
}
```

and use that

```
var json = File.ReadAllText("file.json");
//Deserializing Object to Model Array
var jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model[]>(json);

jsonObj[0].filter = "id = 20"; //<--CALLING PROPERTY DIRECTLY

var output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
File.WriteAllText("file.json", output);
```