# Find a node in JSON file, update the content and save back into the JSON file using c#

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

Current JSON file looks like this

```
[ 
 {
    "name": "company xyz",
    "path": "C:\\xxx\\xyz"   
 },   
 {
    "name": "company abc",
    "path": "C:\\xxx\\abc"   
 } 
]
```

Client Class

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Path { get; set; }
```

I use the below to pull from the file and display in a combo, this works fine

```
public static List<Client> GetList()
{
    // Retrieve JSON data from file
    var json = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Client>>(json);
}
```

I would now like to be able to Search for a specific node and Update that content.  I have the below code so far which does find the node based on the search string I pass but I'm at a loss at how to now Save the updated node (found) back into the JSON file whilst removing the previous?

```
public static void Update(Client c, string s)
{
    var json = File.ReadAllText(fileName);

    List<Client> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Client>>(json);

    Client found = list.Where(x => x.Name == s).Single();

    found.Name = c.Name;
    found.Path = c.Path;

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change values in JSON file (writing files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21695185/change-values-in-json-file-writing-files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void Update(Client c, string s)
{
    var json = File.ReadAllText(fileName);

    List<Client> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Client>>(json);

    Client found = list.Where(x => x.Name == s).Single();

    found.Name = c.Name;
    found.Path = c.Path;

    var updatedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
    File.WriteAllText(fileName, updatedJson);
}
```