# Overwrite single json object instead of the whole file

Tags: c#, json.net

I am deserializing a json object, changing it, and want to save it in the `.json` again. Is there a way to overwrite the single object that was changed instead of the whole `.json` file?

Comment: unlikely to be possible with json.net out of the box.
You might implement a `CustomConverter` for this.

Comment: I fail to understand what's the issue with deserializing the whole thing, applying the desired changes, and serializing and writing it back to the file again. Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Aside from anything else, file systems don't generally allow portions to be removed or added - so unless the JSON for the new object was *exactly* the same size, you'd either run out of space or need to add padding.

If you're worried about the performance hit of rewriting the entire file, you might consider reorganizing your storage to use multiple files - but only do this after actually validating that there's a performance issue. If you're trying to achieve high performance in general, simple file IO may well not be as appropriate as using a database or something similar which is tuned for performance.

Comment: [This works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21695462).