# Deserialise JSON and access content using Linq to JSon

Tags: c#, .net, json, linq, deserialization

I have the following JSON stored in a cookie that I wish to parse:

```
{"package":[{"id":"5054","nodeId":"3286"},{"id":"8888","nodeId":"7777"}], "hotel":[{"id":"3421","nodeId":"1234"},{"id":"8748","nodeId":"2435"}], "activity":[{"id":"5054","nodeId":"3286"},{"id":"8888","nodeId":"7777"},{"id":"2131","nodeId":"2342"}]}
```

I understand from the accepted answer on this question [Deserializing JSON to .NET object using Newtonsoft (or LINQ to JSON maybe?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749639/deserializing-json-to-net-object-using-newtonsoft-or-linq-to-json-maybe) that you can use the following code to access individual objects within JSON notation:

```
JToken token = JObject.Parse(stringFullOfJson);

int page = (int)token.SelectToken("page");
int totalPages = (int)token.SelectToken("total_pages");
```

I've therefore adapted this into my code as follows:

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("wishlist");
string JSONstring = string.Empty;
string nodeId = string.Empty;

if (cookie != null)
{
    JSONstring = cookie.Value;
    JToken token = JObject.Parse(JSONstring);
}
```

I now wish to only retreive the package array for example and loop through each of the items in this array and output the ids in the following format:

```
5054,8888
```

From the example code I sort of came up with the following approach but i'm not sure if i'm proceeding in the right direction.

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(JSONstring);
JArray packages = (JArray)obj["package"];
```

What is the best way of specifying one of the arrays eg. hotel, package , looping through their contents and outputting each of the id nodes that are found? The nodeId will always be numeric but the id could be a string or an int so this adds another layer of complication.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I apologise if this is a sumwhat stupid or easy question however I have jsut started working with .Net and OO so some of the concepts are still a bit foggy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trawling Google, this is the easiest solution I have come up with:

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("wishlist");
string JSONstring = string.Empty;
string nodeId = string.Empty;
string test = string.Empty;

if (cookie != null)
{
    JSONstring = cookie.Value;
    JObject obj = JObject.Parse(JSONstring);
    JArray packages = (JArray)obj["package"];

    foreach (var item in packages.Children()){
        var properties = item.Children<JProperty>();
        var idElement = properties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "id");
        var myElementValue = idElement.Value;

        test = test + myElementValue + ",";
    }
}
```

This will output all ids in the packages array in a CSV format (with a trailing ,)

Comment: Wouldn't this be shorter: `var jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<dynamic>>>(JSON);
       var csv = String.Join(",", jObj.SelectMany(x => x.Value).Select(x => x.id));`

Comment: Well this seems to work but could you explain it in a little more detail for myself and others to understand then maybe I will be able to mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's How I would Do This, I'd Create the classes required to Deserialize the JSON :-

```
    public class JSONCookie
    {
        public Package[] package { get; set; }
        public Hotel[] hotel { get; set; }
        public Activity[] activity { get; set; }
    }

    public class Package
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string nodeId { get; set; }
    }

    public class Hotel
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string nodeId { get; set; }
    }

    public class Activity
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string nodeId { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, I would Create a method that actually does the deserialising :-

```
public JSONCookie GetJSONCookieResponse()
        {
            try
            {
                // Add your own code that gets the Response Here.

                // string response = "{"package":[{"id":"5054","nodeId":"3286"},{"id":"8888","nodeId":"7777"}], "hotel":[{"id":"3421","nodeId":"1234"},{"id":"8748","nodeId":"2435"}], "activity":[{"id":"5054","nodeId":"3286"},{"id":"8888","nodeId":"7777"},{"id":"2131","nodeId":"2342"}]}";

                //return new JsonSerializer().Deserialize<JSONCookie>(new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(response)));
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

From the JSONCookie Object that is returned, you can then use LINQ to pick out what you need like follows :-

```
x.package.Select(p=>p.id);
```

Comment: Thanks for this Derek. I neglected to mention that this will all be run in a razor view so as far as I know, classes aren't really an option and are probably a little heavyweight for this solution.

Comment: @Derek You don't need 3 diffeent classes *Package* *Hotel* and *Activity*. A single class *Node* is enough