# Using WebApi in MVC4, how can I deserialize dynamic json to a concrete type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm experimenting with the MVC4 WebApi for building rest/json services.

In my controller I have the method:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(dynamic message)
```

This contains a single object which always has two fields, type and action.

Action is either Create or Cancel.

I wrote three classes, Message, CreateMessage and CancelMessage, Message is the base class the other two inherit.

After reading the blurb on `dynamic` I thought I'd be able to do this:

```
    public void ProcessMessage(dynamic message)
    {
        switch ((string)message.action)
        {
            case "CREATE":
                ProcessCreateMessage(message);
                break;
            case "CANCEL":
                ProcessCancelMessage(message);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void ProcessCancelMessage(CancelMessage message)
    {
          //Cancell
    }

    private void ProcessCreateMessage(CreateMessage message)
    {
        //Create
    }
```

But I just get either a message about there not being an overload (implicit cast) or "Cannot convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to 'CancelMessage'"

The classes

```
public class Message
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string action { get; set; }
}

public class CancelMessage : Message
{
    public string ref { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

The Json:

```
{
    "type" : "type",
    "action" : "cancel",
    "ref" : "RefNo",
    "message" : "a message"
}
```

What am I not getting here?

Answer (score 2):

You can deserialize JSON to c# object like

```
var cancelMessage = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<CancelMessage>(message);
```

I think that you can't cast string(JSON) to object by default.

Comment: Same problem here, Deserialize only expects a string

Comment: Try cast 'message' to string.

Answer (score 1):

Please go through Arcrain's answer.

[Deserializing JSON to .NET object using Newtonsoft (or LINQ to JSON maybe?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749639/deserializing-json-to-net-object-using-newtonsoft-or-linq-to-json-maybe)

I think in your case It will help you from the same url link.

```
You can use the C# dynamic type to make things easier. This technique also makes re-factoring simpler as it does not rely on magic-strings.

Json

The json string below is a simple response from an http api call and it defines two properties: Id and Name.

{"Id": 1, "Name": "biofractal"}

C#

Use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>() to deserialize this string into a dynamic type then simply access its properties in the usual way.

var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
var id = results.Id;
var name= results.Name;

Note: The NuGet link for the NewtonSoft assembly is http://nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json
```

Hope it will resolve your problem.

Comment: I don't have the Json though, I already have a dynamic object. I tried `var cancelMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CancelMessage>(message);` and I just get a runtime error saying Deserialize expects a string.

Comment: @RoboJ1M try JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CancelMessage.message>(message);

Comment: I've got it, `var createMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CreateMessage>(message.ToString());` where message is a JObject. JObject's ToString() overload returns the underlying Json string

Comment: Ok Good try..well done...thanks i will also care about it in future.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution, using information posted by Janty and Babinicz

Using the ApiController in MVC 4 as I am, if you state `dynamic` as your single incoming parameter.

(I'm following Microsoft's beginner's guides to Web Api in MVC4)

When you try to cast `dynamic` to something, it's supposed to magically work, but I was getting an error.

Tried writing a custom cast operator, but you can't do that to or from dynamic

But it appears that `dynamic` is a lot like `object` in that it knows what it's underlying type is, and that type is Newtonsoft's JObject

And that casting to and from `dynamic` just does normal casting, compiled at runtime instead of design time.

So by adding implicit cast operators to the model classes:

```
public class Message
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string action { get; set; }
}

public class CancelMessage : Message
{
    public string ref { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator CancelMessage(JObject message)
    {
        var output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CancelMessage>(message.ToString());            
        return output;
    }
}

public void ProcessMessage(dynamic message)
{
    switch ((string)message.action)
    {
        case "CANCEL":
            ProcessCancelMessage(message);
            break;
    }
}

private void ProcessCancelMessage(CancelMessage message)
{
      //Cancel
}
```

That just works.

Of course, it's also arguable that if I just pass this `dynamic` thing around, my code will just work as long as the field names in the json match what's expected.