# Deserialize JSON using C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize this JSON string to different objects in C# using `Newtonsoft.Json`

```
{"apple":{"title":"apple","color":"red"},"banana":{"title":"banana","color":"yellow"}}
```

Note "apple" and "banana" in this example are dynamic values, so it's very well possible that suddenly it's called something others, e.g. ananas.

Now what I'm trying to do is deserialize this JSON string in a way that I can do a foreach loop through all the objects (Apple, Banana, ...) to read the value of the `color` field.

But apparently I'm doing something wrong, this is my code.

```
dynamic d = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
            foreach (dynamic e in d)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.title);
            }
```

Does anyone know why this does not work like this?

Comment: I haven't used this module in a while but is there a reason why the solution in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749639/deserializing-json-to-net-object-using-newtonsoft-or-linq-to-json-maybe doesn't work? Also, what error are you getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to do `e.Value.title` instead of just `e.title`.

[DotNetFiddle example here.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/F0yga2)

Answer (score 1):

`e` is a `KeyValuePair<String,JToken>` so we need to access `e.Value` to get the `title`.

```
var d = JObject.Parse(@"{""apple"":{""title"":""apple"",""color"":""red""},""banana"":{""title"":""banana"",""color"":""yellow""}}");

foreach (dynamic e in d)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Value.title);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `System.Web.Script.Serialization` then doing the following:

```
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dict = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(YOURJSON);
```

To use this do:

```
string item = dict["name"];
string itema = dict["item"]["thing"];
```

Hope this helps.