# How to get data from API request?

Tags: c#, api

I'm pretty new to C# and this is my first time getting data from an api. I was wondering how do I get or call the data collected in this api request (MakeRequest). Preferably assign the data to a public string. The data from the api request is in json format.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;

namespace CSHttpClientSample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {         
        public async void MakeRequest()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

            // Request headers
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "{subscription key}");

            // Request parameters
            queryString["seasonId"] = "{string}";
            var uri = "https://www.haloapi.com/stats/{title}/servicerecords/arena?players={players}&" + queryString;

            var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: first of all, `async void` is not a good idea. second: what is your problem with that code? What do you want to achieve? And what did you try?

Comment: I wish to collect json data from that api request.

Comment: so your respose is likely to be the JSON string you downloaded. there you have it. so you "collected" it if you will. but I suppose you want to deserialize that JSON string to any business objects, right?

Comment: I'm pretty new to c# and coding in general. This code was provided and I'm not sure where it's downloading the json string. I wish go access the gathered json data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [deserializing JSON to .net object using NewtonSoft (or linq to json maybe?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749639/deserializing-json-to-net-object-using-newtonsoft-or-linq-to-json-maybe)

Comment: I think he is not at deserializing yet but looking for the JSON he downloaded

Answer (score 1):

So if the call succeeded, you should have your JSON string returned in the `response` variable you assign in the last line.

Use your debugger and inspect that variable. If you look at the MSDN doc for your `GetAsync()` method ([Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158944(v=vs.118).aspx)), you can easily find out that the variable is of the type `HttpResponseMessage`. This class has an own page [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage(v=vs.118).aspx) telling you that there's a property `Content`.

This is your JSON string, now might come the part where you have to do some deserializing. Have fun.