# How to get the values of specific properties from a nested JObject

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JObject:

```
{
  "config": {
    "DataSource": {
      "connectionString": "Localserver",

      "sqlExpression": "select id As 'key', logHeader As 'Label' from Log"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I get the value of `connectionString` and `sqlExpression`?

I am trying:

```
JObject result = new JObject(
             data["DataSource"]
             .SelectMany(jt => jt["properties"]));

string connectionString = result.GetValue("connectionString").ToString();
string sqlExpression = result.GetValue("sqlExpression").ToString();
```

However, I'm not getting the results.  Any suggestions?

Comment: So you are doing it with Json.Net? You have C# object serialized, so you could just deserialize it and read out the data to your needs from the object.

Comment: More answers see [deserializing JSON to .net object using NewtonSoft (or linq to json maybe?)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4749639)

Answer (score 3):

For this simple JSON structure you can use the [`SelectToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken.htm) method navigate to each property value:

```
JObject result = JObject.Parse(json);
string connectionString = (string)result.SelectToken("config.DataSource.connectionString");
string sqlExpression = (string)result.SelectToken("config.DataSource.sqlExpression");
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/00X6kX