# c# Json reading child object

Tags: c#, json, linq, c#-4.0, json.net

I am trying to read child elements in the Json object below. Below is the Json example. I want to read `RecommendedCount` and `TotalReviewCount` in `testdata1, testdata2 and testdata3.`

```
{
    "HasErrors": false,
    "Includes": {
        "test ": {
            "testdata1": {
                "ReviewStatistics": {
                    "RecommendedCount": 0,
                    "TotalReviewCount": 2
                }
            },
            "testdata2": {
                "ReviewStatistics": {
                    "RecommendedCount": 0,
                    "TotalReviewCount": 2
                }
            },
            "testdata3": {
                "ReviewStatistics": {
                    "RecommendedCount": 0,
                    "TotalReviewCount": 2
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the code below.

```
 RecommendedCount = apiResponse.Includes.Products[key].ReviewStatistics.RecommendedCount,
 TotalReviewCount = apiResponse.Includes.Products[key].ReviewStatistics.TotalReviewCount
```

But this is very slow as the Json response has more than 1000 lines so it is taking time. I want to know is there any linq i can use to find the relevant data or any other methods i can use?

Thanks in advance.

```
 var jObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(rawJson);
                foreach (var child in jObj["test"].Children())
                {

                }
```

The above is the deserialize code i am trying to use but getting `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. error

Comment: Can you show us code used for deserialzation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var recList= obj.SelectTokens("$..ReviewStatistics.RecommendedCount").ToList();
var totalList= obj.SelectTokens("$..ReviewStatistics.TotalReviewCount").ToList();
```

Then you can get the data that you want. For example, if you want RecommendedCount from testdata2, you do like this

```
var dataYouWant = (int)recList[1];
```

References:

- http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm
- [Deserializing JSON to .NET object using Newtonsoft (or LINQ to JSON maybe?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749639/deserializing-json-to-net-object-using-newtonsoft-or-linq-to-json-maybe?rq=1)
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197957(v=vs.95).aspx

If there is anything wrong, please feel free to correct my answer. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the answer. What about if i just want to get a testdata2 RecommendedCount and TotalReviewCount?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the problem is in your `Json` you have a space in the field `"test "` which is causing a ***null reference exception***.

I'm not entirely sure whether is it copy paste mistake or your getting `Json` string in this format.

Check this [`working code`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EdIlOR) on removing the space.