# Parsing JSON in C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, json

I'm using C#.Net and am trying to parse out some JSON.

I have this JSON that I retrieve. I've tried to use JavaScriptSerliazer but cannot figure out the correct structure.

What is the best way to parse this JSON to get each array (first, second, third, etc)?

```
{
"first":["A","B"],
"second":["C","D"],
"third":["E","F","G","H","I"],
"fourth":["J","K","L","M","N"]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [deserializing JSON to .net object using NewtonSoft (or linq to json maybe?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749639/deserializing-json-to-net-object-using-newtonsoft-or-linq-to-json-maybe)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5):

Create a class like this:

```
public class RootObject
{
   public List<string> first { get; set; }
   public List<string> second { get; set; }
   public List<string> third { get; set; }
   public List<string> fourth { get; set; }
}
```

Courtesy: [json2charp](http://json2csharp.com/)

Use NewtonSoft Json:

```
RootObject tmp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Then manipulate tmp object as you want