# Deserialize two values into the same property

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a client which can call two different versions of a service.

One service only sends a single value:

```
{
  "value" : { ... }
}
```

The second service always returns multiple values:

```
{
  "values" : [ 
    { ... },
    { ... }
  ]
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to represent this with a single object in my client classes so the user never sees whether it's a single value or multiple values.

```
public class MyValues
{
  public List<Stuff> Values { get; set; }
  public Thing Other { get; set; }
}
```

I think that the only way I'll be able to accomplish this is with a custom `JsonConverter` class which I apply to `MyValues`, but I really only want to do something custom when I'm deserializing the property `value`.  I can't seem to figure out if an IContractResolver would be a better way to go (e.g. somehow attach a *phantom property* to MyValues that deserializes `value` and puts it into `Values`.

If I create a custom converter, how to I tell it to deserialize everything else normally (e.g. if `Other` has an extra properties make sure they are handled appropriately, etc.)

Comment: You could write a converter and map to one or the other depending on what type it is.  Similar problem: [Deserialize json property as bool or double](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39347858/1070452)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a [custom `JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) that has special processing for a few properties of a type but uses default processing for the remainder, you can load the JSON into a [`JObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm), detach and process the custom properties, then populate the remainder from the `JObject` with [`JsonSerializer.Populate()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Populate.htm), like so:

```
class MyValuesConverter : CustomPropertyConverterBase<MyValues>
{
    protected override void ProcessCustomProperties(JObject obj, MyValues value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Remove the value property for manual deserialization, and deserialize
        var jValue = obj.GetValue("value", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase).RemoveFromLowestPossibleParent();
        if (jValue != null)
        {
            (value.Values = value.Values ?? new List<Stuff>()).Clear();
            value.Values.Add(jValue.ToObject<Stuff>(serializer));
        }
    }
}

public abstract class CustomPropertyConverterBase<T> : JsonConverter where T : class
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var jObj = JObject.Load(reader);
        var contract = (JsonObjectContract)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType);
        var value = existingValue as T ?? (T)contract.DefaultCreator();

        ProcessCustomProperties(jObj, value, serializer);

        // Populate the remaining properties.
        using (var subReader = jObj.CreateReader())
        {
            serializer.Populate(subReader, value);
        }

        return value;
    }

    protected abstract void ProcessCustomProperties(JObject obj, T value, JsonSerializer serializer);

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JToken RemoveFromLowestPossibleParent(this JToken node)
    {
        if (node == null)
            return null;
        var contained = node.AncestorsAndSelf().Where(t => t.Parent is JContainer && t.Parent.Type != JTokenType.Property).FirstOrDefault();
        if (contained != null)
            contained.Remove();
        // Also detach the node from its immediate containing property -- Remove() does not do this even though it seems like it should
        if (node.Parent is JProperty)
            ((JProperty)node.Parent).Value = null;
        return node;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Rather than writing a `JsonConverter`, you could make a set-only property `Value` on your `MyValues`, like so:

```
public class MyValues
{
    [JsonProperty]
    Stuff Value
    {
        set
        {
            (Values = Values ?? new List<Stuff>(1)).Clear();
            Values.Add(value);
        }
    }

    public List<Stuff> Values { get; set; }
    public Thing Other { get; set; }
}
```

It could be public or private if marked with [`[JsonProperty]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm).  In this case Json.NET will call the `Value` setter if the singleton `"value"` property is encountered in the JSON, and call the `Values` setter if the array `"values"` property is encountered.  Since the property is set-only only the array property will be re-serialized.

Comment: This is a great simple solution to my problem.  The only reason I'm not marking it as the answer is that the question is slightly more geared towards making a JsonConverter.  This also solves my problem perfectly well.