# JSON.NET Deserialization: Ignore Properties When Types Do Not Match

Tags: c#, json.net

Here is the issue that I am trying to resolve. I have two *different classes* which I have *no ownership of*, and for most properties, if the names match, then the types match as well.  The only properties that I care about are the ones where the name and type match, missing properties or properties with mismatched types can all be ignored.

My work around was to do this:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
     MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore,
     Error = (sender, eventArgs) => eventArgs.ErrorContext.Handled = true
};
```

but I feel that this may be a bit too heavy handed, and could end up biting me later due to the fact it ignores all errors.

**Is there a more elegant way that exclusively targets errors when the property types do not match?**

Comment: [An example using a custom converter to do something similar to what you describe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39351555/1070452)

Comment: Maybe conditional property serialization if the classes are related: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/conditionalproperties.htm. If not, try using reflection and compare the properties with the PropertyInfo class.

Comment: I think this is the easiest way.  However, you might want to not ignore `JsonReaderException` exceptions because these indicate a malformed JSON file.