# Deserializing complex JSON to C#

Tags: c#, json, .net, serialization, orm

When getting data from external API, I receive an object where a value is false when it is empty.

For example:

```json
"product_id": [7800,"Bananenblad Naturel - 484"]
```

OR

```json
"product_id": false
```

```json
"picking_date": false
```

OR

```json
"picking_date": "2023-08-11 10:10:39"
```

How can deserialize this kind of object?

An example of the object:

```json
{
  "id": 1111,
  "product_id": [
    2222,
    "test 1"
  ],
  "product_qty": 1.0,
  "picking_date": false,
  "partner_id": [
    10,
    "Funeral"
  ],
  "picking_id": [
    20,
    "Testing"
  ],
  "picking_state": "cancel"
}, 
{
  "id": 2222,
  "product_id": [
    3333,
    "Primus"
  ],
  "product_qty": 1.0,
  "picking_date": "2023-08-11 10:10:39",
  "partner_id": false,
  "picking_id": false,
  "picking_state": "cancel"
}
```

I've tried using JSON converter options, ignore error handling with deserializer, ... different types of object types etc.

This is the full response:

{
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"id": null,
"result": [{
"id": 3529,
"product_id": [
6000,
"484"
],
"entrepreneur": false,
"deceased_name": false,
"case_number": false,
"product_uom_qty": 1.0,
"picking_date_to": false,
"picking_date_from": false,
"write_date": "2023-08-11 10:10:39",
"create_date": "2021-03-06 16:38:57",
"partner_id": [
1000,
"Zeeland"
],
"picking_id": [
57,
"00045"
],
"picking_state": "cancel",
"batch_id": false
}, {
"id": 3710,
"product_id": [
7244,
"143 (Inwendig 195 cm, Inwendig 56 cm, Nova - 23 Ongebleekt katoen met koord)"
],
"entrepreneur": false,
"deceased_name": false,
"case_number": false,
"product_uom_qty": 1.0,
"picking_date_to": false,
"picking_date_from": false,
"write_date": "2023-08-11 10:10:39",
"create_date": "2021-03-11 21:33:06",
"partner_id": [
108116,
"Afgehaald"
],
"picking_id": [
78,
"00054"
],
"picking_state": "cancel",
"batch_id": false
}
]
}

Where false value = empty. If it's not false - for entrepreneur it's a string, product_uom_qty an integer, write_date a date, ...

Comment: What does it send if the value is `false`?!?

Comment: Please see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39347858/deserialize-json-property-as-bool-or-double. This link shows how to deserialize a property value as a bool or a double. You can write your own JsonConverters to deserialize to string or bool or datetimes.

Comment: *"An example of the object"*: that's two objects and not valid JSON. Is it an array?

Comment: What serializer are you using Newtonsoft or Microsoft?

Comment: That JSON is shocking! Do you have any influence at all over the production of the JSON from the external API? I would be concerned writing a converter to wrangle this into an object model. The producer has not understood JSON de/serialisation and I would worry that successive versions of the API could include more nastiness and break the converter.

Comment: Assuming "id" always has a real value, i.e. is never false, what about the other elements, "product_qty", "partner_id", "picking_id", "picking_state"? Can they also take a value of false if empty?

Comment: @swatsonpicken I have no influence at all over the production of the JSON. And it is not only deserializing this object, after this I also need to POST the correct object back to it...

Comment: @HereticMonkey it says false when it's a bool.

Comment: @trincot: I added the full json. my bad

Comment: @swatsonpicken: they can aslo have the value false when empty. false is always used when a value is empty.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this code

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

    var products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(json);

public class BoolJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type != JTokenType.Boolean)
            if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
                return token.ToObject<List<object>>();
            else return token.ToObject<DateTime>();
        return null;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

class

```
public partial class Product
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("product_id")]
    public List<object> ProductId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("product_qty")]
    public long ProductQty { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(BoolJsonConverter))]
    [JsonProperty("picking_date")]
    public DateTime? PickingDate { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(BoolJsonConverter))]
    [JsonProperty("partner_id")]
    public List<object> PartnerId { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(BoolJsonConverter))]
    [JsonProperty("picking_id")]
    public List<object> PickingId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("picking_state")]
    public string PickingState { get; set; }
}
```