# How to read Json Object in C#

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to read json object contain some values in JsonArray using Json.NET library.  I want to get each array value into variables. Following is the Json String. Please guide, thanks.

```
{"enad_list":
      [{
        "et_cnic":"1090202369011",
        "et_name":"Its me",
        "et_father_husband_name":"My father name",
        "et_present_add":"Its my address",
        "et_permanent_add":"Its my another address ",
        "et_date_of_birth":"10-9-1982",
        "et_birth_place":"My Birth place",
        "et_expiry_date":"2020-12-15"
       }]
}
```

Edit:
So far i have tried this code and getting an error. Please see image for error

```
    string jsonData =@"{""enad_list"":[{""et_cnic"":""1090202369011"",""et_name"":""Its me""}]}";
    dynamic jsonData = JObject.Parse(abc.ToString());
    int cnic = jsonData.enad_list.et_cnic;
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNqAW.png)
[image]

Comment: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json has examples easy peasy

Comment: What is the question? Are you asking which method to use to deserialize this string? Have you checked the documentation or simply googled for this? Did you try something that failed?

Comment: This answer is what you need I guess: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749639/deserializing-json-to-net-object-using-newtonsoft-or-linq-to-json-maybe/10718128#10718128

Comment: @Panagiotis, yes i need to get each array value into variables whichever method we use, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like this for multiple array values

```
dynamic jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(your_json)
int cnic = jsonData.enad_list[0].et_cnic;
```

OR for single string

```
dynamic jsonData = JObject.Parse(your_json-string); 
int cnic = jsonData.et_cnic;
```

Comment: Please see Edit portion of my original thread. I facing error while using your code, thanks.

Comment: Thanks i got it. Its working now. Just need little explanation that what does it mean to DeserializeObject here? while we get only from single string(your second portion of code)?. Sorry new to Json, thanks.

Comment: DeserializeObject Deserializes the JSON to a .NET object. JSON is a format that encodes objects in a string. Serialization means to convert an object into that string, and deserialization is its inverse operation.

Comment: Thanks Dear Masood.