# How can i post resquest in C# as similar to python

Tags: c#, python, asp.net

**Python code to c# .net for HTTP Post to API**

response = requests.post(auth_url, auth=('apitoken', api_token), data={'grant_type': 'client_credentials'})

response.raise_for_status()

access_token = response.json()['access_token']

auth_header = 'Bearer ' + access_token

header = {'Authorization': auth_header}

Comment: Feel free to tag me (@john) if this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: @John can please let me know to access this peace of code access_token = response.json()['access_token']

Comment: I recommend the `Newtonsoft.Json` library for that. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41239713/3181933). Specific to your question, the code might look like `dynamic parsedResponse = JObject.Parse(responseString); var accessToken = parsedResponse.access_token;`. Not that you should typically deserialize to C# objects, rather than dynamic, though I think in this case it's probably OK :)