# Search in a json API using VB.net

Tags: json, vb.net

hello guys i want to search in a json string and get a value of one of the attribute i have the following code

```
    Dim ser As JObject = JObject.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd())

    Dim data As List(Of JToken) = ser.Children().ToList

    Response.Write(ser)
```

and this is my out put

> { "success": true, "result": { "access_token":
>   "T1RLAQLTD+AB7uveLzir/oF8EKbu32EJIRDHKkx5O/W2+ri3cbWT8uOuAADAF7OJij6m20nPrYZzWRwNlDA99fzg/pnN7eL8XiWS9pkvapQtPDhiPHupNJOettLKPJRuekAO0zBgptPAkYt1G6etINlTjHLpW2kVOxeAqH7t3mSzXmScSQvgQwMC2d4FBdZu2jKgSf86ret2i0eHydFW91vJ1eWI9LkZFPrHBXPzlQJZ9GyvFpF2IEVo2D23y3xMYYEVI410ZRKLnTLvTcrH12s/8wYNc8jKLMWKcNNjiKnDm8i0WJS7eOU7iXKu",
>   "token_type": "bearer", "expires_in": 604800 } }

i want to get the value of that  "access_token"   thank you

Comment: Maybe it is useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749639/deserializing-json-to-net-object-using-newtonsoft-or-linq-to-json-maybe?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it without using ToList() first:

```
Dim myAccessToken as String = ser("result")("access_token").Value(Of String)()
```

I haven't checked it, but I think this should work.

Comment: Accessed JObject values with invalid key value: 0. Object property name expected.

Comment: Yes, it had a mistake. Try now, please