# JSON - Newtonsoft Access Value

Tags: json, json.net

How do I get the binary data of the buffer in C#?

```
item = {[_buffer, JVBERi0xLjMKJeLjz9MKMiAwIG9iago8PAovQ3JlYXRpb25EYXR]}
```

I tried this but get an error:

```
 HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var dataStream = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var parsed = JObject.Parse(dataStream);
                if (dataStream == null)
                    return HttpNotFound();

                foreach (dynamic item in parsed)
                {
                    // If user decides to save the file, this will help...
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=" + Path.GetFileName(fileDoc));
                    return File(item._buffer, "application/pdf");
                }
            }
```

Comment: What JSON does the `dataStream` variable contain?

Comment: dataStream = "{\"_buffer\":\"JVBERi0xLjMKJeLjz9MKMiAwIG9iago8PAovQ3JlYXRpb25EYXRlIChEOjIwMTgwMTI2MjI0ODI1LTA1JzAwJykKL01vZERhdGUgKEQ6MjAxODAxMjYyMjQ4MjUtMDUnMDAnKQovUHJvZHVjZXIgKEJDTCBlYXN5UERGIDcuMDAgXCgwMzU1XCkpCi9DcmVhdG9yIChlYXN5UERGIFNESyA3IDcuMCkKPj4KZW5kb2JqCgo4I...

Comment: Your `dataStream` in your comment contains some odd Unicode characters such as [zero-width non-joiners](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/index.htm).  Try to copy & paste the comment text into Visual Studio and you will see them.  Are those really present?  Can you [edit] your question to show the actual JSON the way e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4749639/3744182) does?

Comment: This is my "parsed" from above: item={
  [
    _buffer,
    JVBERi0xLjMKJeLjz9MKMiAwIG9iag
  ]
}

Comment: `{ [ _buffer, JVBERi0xLjMKJeLjz9MKMiAwIG9iag ] }` isn't valid JSON.  Upload it to https://jsonlint.com/ and you will see an error.  What I'm hoping for is to see an example of the "raw" JSON you are receiving so I can test a solution.  Otherwise I could guess at a solution but it might or might not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your raw JSON looks something like this:

```
{
  "_buffer": "JVBERi0xLjMKJeLjz9MKMiAwIG9iago8PAovQ3JlYXRpb25EYXRlIChEOjIwMTgwMTI2MjI0ODI1LTA1JzAwJykKL01vZERhdGUgKEQ6MjAxODAxMjYyMjQ4MjUtMDUnMDAnKQovUHJvZHVjZXIgKEJDTCBlYXN5UERGIDcuMDAgXCgwMzU1XCkpCi9DcmVhdG9yIChlYXN5UERGIFNESyA3IDcuMCkKPj4KZW5kb2JqCgo4"
}
```

Then the value of the "_buffer" property would appear to be [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded binary.  As documented in its [serialization guide](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationguide.htm#PrimitiveTypes) Json.NET supports automatically deserializing Base64 strings to `byte []`.  Thus you can do:

```
var _buffer = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(dataStream, new { _buffer = (byte[])null })._buffer;
```

Then pass the returned byte array to [`Controller.File(Byte[], String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.File%28System.Byte[],System.String%29).

By using [`JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm) you avoid the need to load your (possibly large) response into an intermediate `JToken` hierarchy, and also avoid the need to create an explicit, concrete type just to deserialize a single `byte []` property.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it.