# Convert JSon to dynamic object in VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, json.net, json-deserialization

I am using VB.Net and calling salesforce API. It returns very ugly `JSON` which I am not able to deserialize. I have a following code using [JSON.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
Dim objDescription As Object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Object)(result)
```

`objDescription` contains many properties, one on=f them in `fields`. But when I write something like `objDescription.fields` it gives me error.

> ```
>   objDescription.fields   Public member 'fields' on type 'JObject' not found. Object
> ```

I am not very sure but I think it C# allow to convert any JSON to dynamic object. How can I use it in `VB.Net`?

Comment: objDescription is of Object type and Object types do not have "fields" property. Maybe you can create it as a strongly type object of your target class

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b I really want to do it but I think there has to a way because this JSon has very lengthy list of properties, array etc......

Comment: Then don't convert it into an object and retain it as JSON object and access the properties like object.GetValue("name of property") and cast it to whatever data type that you expect

Answer (score 3):

You can turn `Option Strict Off` and use `ExpandoObject` which is recognized by JSON.NET. In order to leverage the dynamic features you can use a variable of type object.

```
Option Strict Off

Sub Main    
    Dim jsonData As Object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject)("{""Id"":25}")
    Dim test As Integer = jsonData.Id
    Console.WriteLine(test)
End Sub
```

If you would like to use JObject because you need some of its features, you can index the JObject instead.

```
Sub Main
    Dim jsonData As Object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Object)("{""Id"":25}")
    Dim test = jsonData("Id")
    Console.WriteLine(test)
End Sub
```