# How to Deserialize Json Object - C#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, javascriptserializer

A web service returns JSON object as blew:

```
JsonString = "{"d":"[{\"sname\":\"S1\",\"region\":\"R1\",\"name\":\"Q1\"},{\"sname\":\"S2\",\"region\":\"R2\",\"name\":\"Q2\"}]"}"
```

I tried to Deserialize by doing this:

1. Define the objects

   ```
   public class RootResponseClass
   {
       public ResponseParametersClass[] d { get; set; }
   }

   public class ResponseParametersClass
   {
       public string sname { get; set; }
       public string region { get; set; }
       public string name { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Write the Deserialize Method

   ```
    JavaScriptSerializer ser2 = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    RootResponseClass obj = new RootResponseClass();

    obj = ser2.Deserialize<RootResponseClass>(JsonString);
   ```

But It is gives error "Cannot convert object of type 'System.String' to type 'NAS.Helpers.ResponseParametersClass[]", So how can i do it!

**Solution**

```
 public class RootResponseClass
    {
        public string d { get; set; }
    }
```

And for deserialize method :

```
JavaScriptSerializer ser2 = new JavaScriptSerializer();
RootResponseClass obj = new RootResponseClass();
obj = ser2.Deserialize<RootResponseClass>(JsonString);

List<ResponseParametersClass> obj2 = new List<ResponseParametersClass>();
obj2 = ser2.Deserialize<List<ResponseParametersClass>>(obj.d.ToString());
```

Comment: d in the Json doesn't contain an array, but a string. If it was an array, it'd start like [ instead of "[. So it seems like the Json contains another Json string.

Comment: I recommend using Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: @Dnomyar96 Thanks your comment helps me to see the answer.

Comment: I tired the both, and the other answer works too but using another method, but like you said the problem wasn't in the method, it is in how i deal with the json string, so i did what you recommended in comment and it works fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserializing JSON to .NET object using Newtonsoft (or LINQ to JSON maybe?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749639/deserializing-json-to-net-object-using-newtonsoft-or-linq-to-json-maybe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Json string seems to contain another Json string. So in order to deserialize this, you'd need to deserialize as you're doing now, but change the `ResponseParametersClass` to `string`.

Then you'd need to deserialize the string you just got (as a `List<ResponseParametersClass>`). So in this case you'd need to deserialize in two seperate steps.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the package `using Newtonsoft.Json;` for deserializing JSON

example

```
JsonString = "{"d":"[{\"sname\":\"S1\",\"region\":\"R1\",\"name\":\"Q1\"},{\"sname\":\"S2\",\"region\":\"R2\",\"name\":\"Q2\"}]"}";

var foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootResponseClass>(JsonString);
```

foo is your deserialized object.

**EDIT**

As extra information why the initial way is not working is because your array is starting with quotes so its recognized as a string. After the `"{"d":` should be just `[]` instead of `"[]"`

Thanx Dnomyar96 for pointing that extra out.

Comment: This won't actually help OP. His problem is in the Json string, not the method of deserializing. His method works just as well as this.

Comment: @H. Mikhaeljan, please explain array was not working and you change it to list to make it work, I am not getting this thing.

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta The list is not making the change it can also just be an array im just more used to work with lists excuse me for the confusing change.

Comment: @H.Mikhaeljan ok