# How Get everything after index of a specific character to end?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, split, substring

I'm trying to get some part of string by substring and this is my string :`{"samanState":"OK","samanResNum":"97d590e2-9ce3-49f9-85cf-2228b33cad57","samanTraceNo":"479936"}` I can't do something like this : substring(8,16) because this string is change every time. I want to get `479936` from that. I'm sure `TraceNo":"` is static and never change so I did this :

```
<td>@(bankDepositHistoryItem.AdditionalData.Substring
                                            (bankDepositHistoryItem.AdditionalData.IndexOf("TraceNo\":\""),
                                            bankDepositHistoryItem.AdditionalData.Length- bankDepositHistoryItem.AdditionalData.IndexOf("TraceNo\":\"")-2)) </td>
```

but the out put is : `TraceNo":"479936` How should I get this : `479936`
I have to say that I Know this is possible with serialize and deserialize but I want to know if this is possible with substring or split or methods like these.
Many thanks

Comment: Read about using JSON parsers.

Comment: That looks like json to me. Try to get your value by deserializing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Ok thanks I will read about deserializing

Comment: **Never** parse JSON on your own. This becomes horrible to maintain as soon as your data-structure changes. You should use a deserializer, e.g. NewtonSoft instead.

Comment: Convert the json to an object and then you can use the property and values. e.g. 
`JToken token = JObject.Parse(stringFullOfJson);` . More details can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4749755/218408

Answer (score 0):

That is a JSON string, so I would first convert the string to a .NET object using the popular [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/) framework library.

After adding the Newtonsoft.Json NuGet package to your project, your code would look something like this:

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq //add this to your Razor page or to _ViewImports.cshtml

<td>@(JObject.Parse(bankDepositHistoryItem)["samanTraceNo"])</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to parse the string, you can use a couple of handy string extension methods (I have variations for integers and Regex as well):

```
public static string Past(this string s, string starter) {
    var starterPos = s.IndexOf(starter);
    return starterPos == -1 ? String.Empty : s.Substring(starterPos + starter.Length);
}
public static string UpTo(this string s, string stopper) {
    var stopPos = s.IndexOf(stopper);
    return (stopPos >= 0) ? s.Substring(0, stopPos) : s;
}
```

Then extract with:

```
var ans = bankDepositHistoryItem.Past("\"samanTraceNo\":\"").UpTo("\"");
```