# How can I actually use JSON in C#?

Tags: c#, json

I have a Json file that was deserialized from a Json Api-Call, now I have to use this file as an object in the main program.

Here is a small section of it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Api1
{
    public class EcmSimpleField
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public string internalName { get; set; }
        public string dbName { get; set; }
        public bool visible { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }

    public class BaseParameter
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }

    public class SystemField
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }
```

How can I use this file as an object in the main program and work with it?

Comment: Add the file to your csproj and it will _just work_.

Comment: Maybe duplicated? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749639/deserializing-json-to-net-object-using-newtonsoft-or-linq-to-json-maybe

Answer (score 4):

Create a class for the json like you shared above and use deserialise it using Newtonsoft.json dll or any other library.

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourClass>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

This thread will probably help you:
[How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

If your JSON file has changing parameters then the parameters will need to be retrieved in arrays because the array index will always be the same even if the "parameter" changes.