# Get value from JObject in C#

Tags: c#, json.net

This is my json string in database table

```
{
    "Object":"order",
    "LiveMode":true,
    "Amount":3000,
    "Captured":false,
    "Created":"\/Date(1593359683000)\/",
    "Currency":"usd",
    "Paid":true,
    "List":{
        "Object":"list",
        "Data":[],
        "TotalCount":0
    },
    "Source":{
        "Type":0,
        "Card":{
            "Object":"card",
            "Brand":"Visa",
            "ExpirationMonth":"7",
            "ExpirationYear":"2023",
            "AddressCity":null,
            "AddressCountry":null,
            "Metadata":{},
            "Name":"Lion Mtosh"
        },
        "BankAccount":null,
        "OtherDetails":{}
    }
}
```

How do I retrieve Created date from this string?

```
var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
data["Created"] does not return date value.
```

Comment: please pay attention to [code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: `data["Created"]` does return a date value, you can use even use `.Value<DateTime>();` to convert it to DateTime. The json you posted is missing a closing bracket by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I works for me.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/p6U5GY

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        
        var jsonString = "{\"Object\":\"order\",\"LiveMode\":true,\"Amount\":3000,\"Captured\":false,\"Created\":\"/Date(1593359683000)/\",\"Currency\":\"usd\",\"Paid\":true,\"List\":{\"Object\":\"list\",\"Data\":[],\"TotalCount\":0},\"Source\":{\"Type\":0,\"Card\":{\"Object\":\"card\",\"Brand\":\"Visa\",\"ExpirationMonth\":\"7\",\"ExpirationYear\":\"2023\",\"AddressCity\":null,\"AddressCountry\":null,\"Metadata\":{},\"Name\":\"Lion Mtosh\"},\"BankAccount\":null,\"OtherDetails\":{}}}";
        
        var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
        
        Console.WriteLine(data["Created"]);
    }
}
```

Note: you are missing a closing paren at the end of JSON string.

Answer (score 4):

You can use dynamic object like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10718128/5164814)

```
dynamic results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
var id = results.Id;
var name= results.Name;
```

Answer (score -1):

Define  entity class contains same values name whith the same types
and then make DeserializeObject in the entity

Public class ObjectClass {
public int LiveMode {set;get;}
.
.
.

}
ObjectClass obj = ((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonText)).ToObject();

Comment: call it  --->     obj .Created