# Adding an element to an ArrayList which is nested inside a HashTable (turtles all the way down)

Tags: c#, json, arraylist, nested, hashtable

I have this code which, on the front-end, will create dependent selectboxes (subcategories are dependent on the category) using LINQ:

```
foreach (var cat in (from category in KB.Categories
                     orderby category.name
                     select category)) {
    this.categories.Add(cat.id, cat.name);
}
foreach (var sub_cat in (from subcategory in KB.SubCategories
                      orderby subcategory.name
                      select subcategory)) {
    this.subcategories.Add(sub_cat.id, sub_cat.name);
    if (!this.subcategoryCategory.containsKey) {
        this.subcategoryCategory.Add(sub_cat.category_id, new ArrayList());
    }
    // I'd like to put the sub_cat_id at the end of the arraylist
    // for the category_id, but this line doesn't seem to work
    //this.subcategoryCategory[sub_cat.category_id] = sub_cat.id;
}
```

How can I do this?

Perhaps there a way to build a giant JSON object instead of the three variables (categories, subCategoryCategory, subcategories)?

Is there a **better/different** way to do this that I've completely missed?

P.S. Coming from a different programming paradigm, I'm not doing this in the standard ASP.NET (webforms or MVC) way, but I *am* using codebehind to generate the values.

Comment: Given that you're using LINQ and therefore *must* have generics available, why are you using the old collections instead of `List<T>` etc?

Comment: Because I'm new at this (ASP.NET) and have yet to wrap my head around the whole 'creating a class which defines a variable type' when I can use a generic Hashtable. :) Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: This isn't really an ASP.NET issue. It's "core" .NET. I would strongly suggest you try to get your head round generics before you do any more LINQ work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you actually want a `Lookup`, e.g.

```
var subcategories = KB.SubCategories.ToLookup(subcat => subcat.id,
                                              subcat => subcat.name);
```

However, it's not really clear given that you've got `subcategories`, `subcategoryCategory` and `categoies`, all of which are instance variables which you haven't shown us the type for... and your `if` clause doesn't specify *which* key it's trying to use. It's all a bit confused at the moment...

My guess is that you should look at [`ToLookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549211.aspx) and also [`ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277.aspx), which are made for this sort of thing.

Comment: They are all `subcategories`, `subCategoryCategory`, and `categories` are all Hashtables. The key I'm looking for should be `sub_cat.id`.

Comment: @Damiro: This is where we're suffering because you're not using the generic collections - it's hard for us to know what you expect when you're using weakly typed collections. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into these. It seems to make the code more clear. The main issue, however is accessing the `ArrayList` within the subCategoryCategory Hashtable. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Damiro: That's only the "main issue" because you're looking at it from the point of view of a decision you've already made - which I don't think is the right decision. If you use ToLookup you'll probably find it's a single statement to do the right thing completely. But we can't easily tell that at the moment.

Comment: So the lookup could create some sort of mapping something along the lines of `{'a':(1,2,3),'b':(4,5,6)}`? My _real_ requirement is that of being able to easily loop through `a` and `b` to output the related numbers `(1,2,3,4,5,6)`.

Comment: @Damiro: Yes. All of that would be very easy.

Answer (score 0):

[JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com) might solve this problem, with its ability to convert JSON objects to C# and back. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246694/how-to-convert-json-object-to-custom-c-object) for an example.