# Convert dictionary to anonymous object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have a dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, object> dict;
```

And i get values from it by typing

```
string foo = dict["foo"].ToString();
```

The dictionary is a serialized JSON result.

```
serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(HttpContext.Current.Request["JSON"]);
```

What i would like to know if thers a way to convert it to an object, so i can type something like:

```
string foo = dict.foo;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know the exact members of the dictionary you can use `dynamic` to get a pretty syntax as shown below. However, if you know the members of the dictionary and the types, [then you could create your own class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246694/how-to-convert-json-object-to-custom-c-sharp-object) and do the conversion yourself. There might exists a framework to do that automatically.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Dynamic;

namespace DynamicTest
{
    public class DynamicDictionary : DynamicObject
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> dict;

        public DynamicDictionary(Dictionary<string, object> dict)
        {
            this.dict = dict;
        }

        public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
        {
            dict[binder.Name] = value;
            return true;
        }

        public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
        {
            return dict.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out result);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            dynamic foo = new DynamicDictionary(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "test1", 1 } });

            foo.test2 = 2;

            Console.WriteLine(foo.test1); // Prints 1
            Console.WriteLine(foo.test2); // Prints 2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That framework does indeed exist and is called [Automapper](http://automapper.org/)