# MVC controller : get JSON object from HTTP body?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, post

We have an MVC (MVC4) application which at times might get a JSON events POSTed from a 3rd party to our specific URL ("http://server.com/events/"). The JSON event is in the body of the HTTP POST and the body is strictly JSON (`Content-Type: application/json` - not a form-post with JSON in some string field).

How can I receive the JSON body inside the controller's body? I tried the following but didn't get anything

**[Edit]**: When I say *didn't get anything* I meant that jsonBody is always null regardless of whether I define it as `Object` or `string`.

```
[HttpPost]
// this maps to http://server.com/events/
// why is jsonBody always null ?!
public ActionResult Index(int? id, string jsonBody)
{
    // Do stuff here
}
```

Note that I know if I give declare the method with a strongly typed input parameter, MVC does the whole parsing and filtering i.e.

```
// this tested to work, jsonBody has valid json data 
// that I can deserialize using JSON.net
public ActionResult Index(int? id, ClassType847 jsonBody) { ... }
```

However, the JSON we get is very varied, so we don't want to define (and maintain) hundreds of different classes for each JSON variant.

I'm testing this by the following `curl` command (with one variant of the JSON here)

```
curl -i -H "Host: localhost" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost/events/ -d '{ "created": 1326853478, "data": { "object": { "num_of_errors": 123, "fail_count": 3 }}}
```

Comment: so how will you parse hundreds of different variants of JSON then, using if/else?

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot: they are dumped to logs as a one JSON object each. So that's why I only care about them as a JSON object or a string - don't care what's inside them.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

It seems that if

- `Content-Type: application/json` and
- if POST body isn't tightly bound to controller's input object class

Then MVC doesn't really bind the POST body to any particular class. Nor can you just fetch the POST body as a param of the ActionResult (suggested in another answer). Fair enough. You need to fetch it from the request stream yourself and process it.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    Stream req = Request.InputStream;
    req.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
    string json = new StreamReader(req).ReadToEnd();

    InputClass input = null;
    try
    {
        // assuming JSON.net/Newtonsoft library from http://json.codeplex.com/
        input = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InputClass>(json)
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Try and handle malformed POST body
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    //do stuff

}
```

**Update:**

for Asp.Net Core, you have to add `[FromBody]` attrib beside your param name in your controller action for complex JSON data types:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult JsonAction([FromBody]Customer c)
```

Also, if you want to access the request body as string to parse it yourself, you shall use `Request.Body` instead of `Request.InputStream`:

```
Stream req = Request.Body;
req.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
string json = new StreamReader(req).ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Note, if you close StreamReader, it closes the stream by default, so if you have anything else reading the stream, make sure you use the overload with `leaveOpen: false` (I forget if the stream is read-once in MVC or not, I know it is in WebAPI)

Comment: It's better to use Model parameters rather than manually reading and deserializing.

Comment: Yes, but that wasn't possible since it was a 3rd party API.

Comment: @afollestad how? can you provide an example. This is because DeepSpace101's answer is working but looks to be too much effort. I thought ASP.NET MVC has some easier way to getting this value from ajax call. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PawanPillai you simply use `InputClass` as the parameter for the Index action method. ASP.NET MVC will automatically bind the incoming JSON to the model obect. Reading the input stream is only useful when the structure of the JSON sent to a single endpoint can change.

Comment: Thank you , you saved my time

Comment: Thanks! I have been searching for a solution for hours and this worked!

Answer (score 6):

use `Request.Form` to get the Data

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        string jsonData= Request.Form[0]; // The data from the POST
    }
```

---

I write this to try

View:

```
<input type="button" value="post" id="btnPost" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var test = {
            number: 456,
            name: "Ryu"
        }
        $("#btnPost").click(function () {
            $.post('@Url.Action("Index", "Home")', JSON.stringify(test));
        });
    });
</script>
```

and write `Request.Form[0]` or `Request.Params[0]` in controller can get the data.

I don't write `<form> tag` in view.

Comment: There is no form in the HTML POST body - the body of the HTML POST is pure json. So Request.Form[0] = null (it's count is 0).

Comment: Not having a `<form>` tag doesn't matter - the HTTP header from your code is `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`. Check the output in fiddler. That's what makes it looks like a FORM submission.

Comment: jQuery uses form encoded data by default when posting AJAX content, that's why the backend gets Form populated

Comment: where does it say jquery is posting data?

Comment: As long as Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; was set, Request.Form[0] works great

Answer (score 3):

I've been trying to get my **ASP.NET MVC controller** to parse some model that i submitted to it using [**Postman**](https://www.getpostman.com/downloads/).

I needed the following to get it to work:

- controller action

  ```
  [HttpPost]
  [PermitAllUsers]
  [Route("Models")]
  public JsonResult InsertOrUpdateModels(Model entities)
  {
      // ...
      return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
  ```
- a Models class

  ```
  public class Model
  {
      public string Test { get; set; }
      // ...
  }
  ```
- headers for Postman's request, specifically, `Content-Type`

  [image: postman headers]
- json in the request body

  [image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are sending raw data from postman body with
`Content-Type: application/json` then it's consider as Stream data. please find the following way to get that.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
{
            
    string Header_Value = string.Empty;
    if (Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Sequeritykey", out var headerValues))
    {
       Header_Value = headerValues;
    }
           
    StreamReader requestReader = new StreamReader(Request.Body);
    JObject request = JObject.Parse(await requestReader.ReadToEndAsync());
    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you define a class (MyDTOClass) indicating what you expect to receive it should be as simple as...

```
public ActionResult Post([FromBody]MyDTOClass inputData){
 ... do something with input data ...
}
```

Thx to Julias:

[Parsing Json .Net Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37447427/parsing-json-net-web-api)

Make sure your request is sent with the http header:

Content-Type: application/json

Comment: That would work in WebAPI, the question refers to MVC.

Comment: It actually doesn't matter whether you're using WebAPI or MVC. As long as client sends a JSON payload that complies with yout DTO, this will work.

Comment: @xjuice If you're using Core, but MVC 5 for example, this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the json string as a param of your `ActionResult` and afterwards serialize it using [**JSON.Net**](http://json.codeplex.com/)

[**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246694/how-to-convert-json-object-to-custom-c-sharp-object) an example is being shown

---

in order to receive it in the serialized form as a param of the controller action you must either write a custom model binder or a Action filter (OnActionExecuting) so that the json string is serialized into the model of your liking and is available inside the controller body for use.

---

[**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object) is an implementation using the dynamic object

Comment: *you can get the json string as a param of your ActionResult* - **how?** That's the original question as I'm unable to get jsonBody with data. jsonBody == null even if I define jsonBody as `string` or `Object` !