# AngularJs Post to WebApi is always null

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

Angular Code:

```
 getAuthorizationStatus: function () {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                     $http({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: url,
                        data: {
                            username: $scope.username,
                            password: $scope.password
                        },
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
                    }
                    }).success(deferred.resolve)
                      .error(deferred.reject);
                    return deferred.promise;
                },
```

My Server side code:

```
  [HttpPost]
        public int ValidateUser([FromBody]Credentials credentials)
        {
            try
            {
                string username = credentials.username;
                string password = credentials.password;
          //Do stuff
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
            return -1;
        }

        return -1; // not valid user
    }
```

The problem I am having is I am able to hit the Api Method but the data inside is always null. I have tried several combinations like this:

```
  data:  JSON.stringify({
                            "username" : "username",
                            "password":"mypassword"
                        }),
```

No dice.

What am I doing in wrong ?

Comment: Why are you using a post?  Look like you want a get.

Comment: Is this really a problem with the client? Any server side web framework should have access to data body posts. What is your server built on here.

Comment: @jbrown No, you don't want to use a get request for username and password!

Answer (score 1):

Enclose your data in $.param()

Example :

`data: $.param({ username: $scope.username,password: $scope.password })`

Comment: Not everyone has access to or wants jQuery in their project. You could also use a request transformer I believe. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1714899/1784301

Comment: Yes, my solution is perfect if you are using jQuery and it makes it really simple to implement. Or if you don't want to use jquery you can refer Sean Larkin's link.

Comment: @amanpurohit, your approach will solve the problem but add an additional dependency. But your answer will help a lot of people I am sure.

Comment: @w2olves, I mentioned it that my solution is apt if the project is jquery dependent.!

Answer (score 1):

I would instead trying to change the default and appropriate behavior of `$http`'s POST, instead let the server read the data from the right place. Taken from [MVC controller : get JSON object from HTTP body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041808/mvc-controller-get-json-object-from-http-body):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    Stream req = Request.InputStream;
    req.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
    string json = new StreamReader(req).ReadToEnd();

    InputClass input = null;
    try
    {
        // assuming JSON.net/Newtonsoft library from http://json.codeplex.com/
        input = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InputClass>(json)
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Try and handle malformed POST body
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    //do stuff

}
```

> It turns out that MVC doesn't really bind the POST body to any
>   particular class. Nor can you just fetch the POST body as a param of
>   the ActionResult (suggested in another answer). Fair enough. You need
>   to fetch it from the request stream yourself and process it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `[FromBody]` beside the action input param is enough to get the data from request. Your problem is that you override the `content-type` in your Angular code through `headers`:

```
contentType: 'application/json',
headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' //*** Remove this!
}
```

It must be **'application/json'** in order to send json data. Just remove that headers and it should work normally.