# POST 500 error when sending JSON stringified javascript object to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently working on a ASP.net Web application with the MVC pattern. I have set up a page where people can add items to a gridstack section and drag them around (Gridstack is a plugin to create draggable boxes/objects). My goal is to send the final coordinates of these boxes to my controller:

```
function saveData() {
    var pagePositions = [];

    // Fill our array
    $('.grid-stack-item.ui-draggable').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        pagePositions.push({
            x: $this.attr('data-gs-x'),
            y: $this.attr('data-gs-y'),
            w: $this.attr('data-gs-width'),
            h: $this.attr('data-gs-height'),
            content: $('.grid-stack-item-content', $this).html()
        });
    });

    // Convert array to object
    var pagePosData = toObject(pagePositions);

    alert(pagePosData);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "savePage",
        data: { positions: JSON.stringify(pagePosData) }
    });

} function toObject(arr) {
    var rv = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
        if (arr[i] !== undefined) rv[i] = arr[i];
    return rv;
}
```

The code above fills the attributes of the given html elements and puts them into an array. I assumed, according to several topics on the internet, that sending the array was causing trouble so i inserted a function that converts the array to an javascript object (key value pairs). I send them to my controller with an AJAX call which results in a error code 500:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string savePage(string positions)
    {
        //some code
        var json = positions;
        var test = "";
        CreatePagemodelJson obj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<CreatePagemodelJson>(positions.ToString());
        //var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CreatePagemodel>(positionsJson.ToString());

        return "";
    }
```

I set up breakpoints inside the controller to read the value i get from the parameter positions, but it doesn't even get to that point. I tried setting up models for the Json file but the problem here is that the post calls return a dynamic json format.

**Update:**
I managed to get it working with below posts. With below structure, i get the results as an array according to my model.

```
function saveData() {
    var pagePositions = [];

    // Fill our array
    $('.grid-stack-item.ui-draggable').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        pagePositions.push({
            x: $this.attr('data-gs-x'),
            y: $this.attr('data-gs-y'),
            w: $this.attr('data-gs-width'),
            h: $this.attr('data-gs-height'),
            content: $('.grid-stack-item-content', $this).html()
        });
    });

    alert(pagePositions);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "savePage",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(pagePositions)
    });
}

public class Position
{
    public string x { get; set; }
    public string y { get; set; }
    public string w { get; set; }
    public string h { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult savePage(IEnumerable<Position> positions)
{
    //some code
    return View("SomeView");
}
```

The parameter positions succesfully returns the array of pagePositions send with the post: 
[image: Succesfull transfer]

I tried sending the data without the JSON.stringify(pagePositions) and ContentType: 'application/json' option but i got a null return in my parameter on the controller.

Comment: Why are you toString'ing a string?  Also have you tried adding breakpoints and debugging step by step to see where the error happens?

Comment: It need to be `data: JSON.stringify(positions) }` and add the `contentType: 'application/json'` option. And then change your method to `public ActionResult savePage(IEnumerable<XX> positions)` where `XX` is a model containing properties `x`, `y`, etc (and delete your `toObject()` function)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you, this worked! I managed to get the results into the controller as an array. I tried the answer below and the only thing that was missing was the JSON.stringify(pagePositions).

Comment: And the `contentType: 'application/json'` option :)

Answer (score 0):

There a number of things to point out here.

With your current question.

- The data you are sending isn't a string. `data: { positions: JSON.stringify(pagePosData) }` is creating a JavaScript object with a property of `positions` whose value is the serialized version of your object.
- You should be able to create a c# class and accept that as your controller methods parameter and get closer to the results you are expecting. That would look as follows:

  public class Foo
    {
      public string Positions { get; set; }
    }

  public string savePage(Foo positions)
- Alternatively you could update your method to get the request body as a string as shown in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041808/mvc-controller-get-json-object-from-http-body#answer-13116824)

More importantly though, it would seem as though you came across some misinformation. There shouldn't be any issue passing an array back to your controller. Again, you will need a c# class that models your expected data type(s). You don't list those in your question, so it is hard to say for sure how you need to update your code, but I would suggest something more like the following:

```
function saveData() {
    var pagePositions = [];

    // Fill our array
    $('.grid-stack-item.ui-draggable').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        pagePositions.push({
            x: $this.attr('data-gs-x'),
            y: $this.attr('data-gs-y'),
            w: $this.attr('data-gs-width'),
            h: $this.attr('data-gs-height'),
            content: $('.grid-stack-item-content', $this).html()
        });
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "savePage",
        data: JSON.stringify(pagePositions),
        contentType: "application/json"
    });
}


public class Position
{
  public int X { get; set; }
  public int Y { get; set; }
  public int W { get; set; }
  public int H { get; set; }
  public string Content { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public string savePage(Position[] positions)
{
    //some code
    return "";
}
```

If this doesn't work, please provide more details about what doesn't work, what error you are receiving and what version of asp.net mvc you are using.

Comment: This indeed solves the POST error, as i am now able to POST to the controller without getting the 500 error. I do however get a null result in the parameter. I got it working with the comment above, adding JSON.stringify(pagePositions) and the contentType: 'application/json' option to the call.