# How to parse Json link Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I try the all Json parse example but they don't work.

Do anyone have a proper example Json parsing from web link for Windows Phone 8 ?

Please help me...

Comment: Have you tried ServiceStack.Text https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text it is a 3rd party json serializer. You can browse the code, it contains some samples.

Comment: I am not good at C#. I will try. Thank you @Mike

Answer (score 0):

1) Generate class for json object ([Online JSON class generator](http://jsonpack.com/))

2) Call link and download data.

3) Parse data using JsonConvert or other class.( [Samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246694/how-to-convert-json-object-to-custom-c-sharp-object) )

Here is a sample:

http://smallandmighty.net/blog/using-json-with-windows-phone

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx). It is light-weight and relatively easy, especially if you read through the documentation. It is hard to answer the 'how to parse' considering there are different scenarios to consider. The resource #1 that Norbert posted I think is helpful and something I am going to use now that i know about it considering creating the classes is usually the longest and most monotonous part.

Comment: There isn't any sample for parsing from web link. Do you any sample that parse Json from web link ?

Comment: Can you post an example of what you are trying to parse? I am confused as to what you mean by "from weblink". I am not an expert at JSON but i think there is some confusion as to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I send you an e-mail. With my code sample and web link to parse.

Comment: did you get the e-mail. I try every way to parse Json from link. Please help me.

Comment: Yes I got it. sorry for the delay. Where did your error occur? Which line? Like I mentioned earlier maybe post your code here so others can see? I am not a Json expert so i am not really sure what is causing the error. Sorry.

Comment: Inside the DownloadStringCompleted  but now I dont remember. e.Result maybe.

Comment: While reading link with WebClient, it gets the Html tag.

So without cleaning Html tag Json parser not parse. 

Before parse with Json parser I cleaned the Html tag then parse with Json parser.

    string str = e.Result.Replace("</string>", "");
    str = str.Replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>", "");
    str = str.Replace("<string xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">", "");

I clean the Html tag with this code.

Now I can parse the my web link.