# Custom JSON, convert to object

Tags: c#, json

I have the result of an API call which looks like:

```
{"Operations":[{"OperationId":"2","OperationObjectId":"Application","OperationName":"UnlockSession","OperationParameters":[{"Name":"viewModel","Value":"model"},{"Name":"returnUrl","Value":"https://"}],"OperationCaller":{"UserPrincipalName":"bob","ClientIPAddress":""},"OperationResult":"Succeeded","OperationStatus":200,"OperationRequest":{"Method":"POST","Url":""},"OperationStartedTime":"2013-08-20T12:04:17.5462357Z","OperationCompletedTime":"2013-08-20T12:04:17.9979469Z"}],"ContinuationToken":null}
```

Ideally I want to convert it to an object so I can do stuff like:

```
object.OperationObjectID; // gives Application
object.Method; // gives POST
object.OperationResult; // gives Succeeded
```

Does any one know how that is done? Does the JSON parse need to be aware of the format?

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: What is meant by "Custom" JSON?

Comment: Please take a look at this StackOverflow answer:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246694/how-to-convert-json-object-to-custom-c-sharp-object][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246694/how-to-convert-json-object-to-custom-c-sharp-object

Comment: Use [json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Json.Net as below

```
dynamic object = JObject.Parse(yorjsonstring);

object.Operations[0].OperationObjectID;
object.Operations[0].Method;
object.Operations[0].OperationResult;
```

rather than using dynamic object you can generate classes for your json and serialize to those classes like below.
you can get help of http://json2csharp.com/ site for generate classes

```
public class OperationParameter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class OperationCaller
{
    public string UserPrincipalName { get; set; }
    public string ClientIPAddress { get; set; }
}

public class OperationRequest
{
    public string Method { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

public class Operation
{
    public string OperationId { get; set; }
    public string OperationObjectId { get; set; }
    public string OperationName { get; set; }
    public List<OperationParameter> OperationParameters { get; set; }
    public OperationCaller OperationCaller { get; set; }
    public string OperationResult { get; set; }
    public int OperationStatus { get; set; }
    public OperationRequest OperationRequest { get; set; }
    public string OperationStartedTime { get; set; }
    public string OperationCompletedTime { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Operation> Operations { get; set; }
    public object ContinuationToken { get; set; }
}
```

then

```
RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonstring);
obj.Operations[0].OperationObjectID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `JavaScriptSerializer` class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx.