# How to create c# class for below json object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am new to json. This is my json object.Anyone please help me to create C# class for the below json object

```
{
   "JBS" : {
      "name" : "Jobsite"
   },
   "LNK" : {
      "name" : "Linked IN"
   },
   "MUK" : {
      "name" : "Monster UK"
   }
}
```

In that I need information of (JBS,jobsite ) like that for n elements.

Comment: this could be found online so easily I suggest you to make some research like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246694/how-to-convert-json-object-to-custom-c-sharp-object

Comment: Does each object have only property "name" ?

Comment: but in my json example "JBS","LNK","MUK" are changing every time .some times I may get n codes so how can I create dynamic class with the names like  JBS","LNK","MUK" for saving n values.

Comment: yes patel, each object has 'name' property only. but the codes(  "JBS","LNK","MUK" ) will change.

Comment: If its possible you should be using structure like

{
   "JBS" : "Jobsite",
   "LNK" : "Linked IN",
   "MUK" : "Monster UK"
}

this would be easier to parse

Comment: no Patel ,I'm getting this type of response from another webservice. so I cannot change this format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to enumerate the result, you should try deserializing into a dictionary. Here's an example that deserializes it and then makes a list of them:

```
var json = "{ \"JBS\" : { \"name\" : \"Jobsite\" }, \"LNK\" : { \"name\" : \"Linked IN\" }, \"MUK\" : { \"name\" : \"Monster UK\" } }";

var result = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, JobSite>>(json);

var jobsites = new List<JobSite>(result.Count);

foreach (var pair in result)
{
    var jobsite = pair.Value;
    jobsite.Short = pair.Key;
    jobsites.Add(jobsite);
}
```

The example uses a class looking like this:

```
public class JobSite
{
    public string Short { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Declare classes as:

```
public class Entity
{
    public string name{get; set;}
}

public class JsonData
{
    public Entity JBS{get;set;}
    public Entity LNK{get;set;}
    public Entity MUK{get;set;}
}
```

then use:

```
var json =
   @"{'JBS' : {'name' : 'Jobsite'},
   'LNK' : {'name' : 'Linked IN'},
   'MUK' : {'name' : 'Monster UK'}}";


JsonData jsonData = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<JsonData>(json);
```

}

**UPDATE**

I think this snippet lays out under your requirements.

```
var json =
@"{ 'JBS' : {'name' : 'Jobsite'},
    'LNK' : {'name' : 'Linked IN'},
    'MUK' : {'name' : 'Monster UK'}}";


var jsonData = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string, string>>>(json)
.ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Value.First().Value);
```

Comment: thanks. but my problem is that I need to capture what are the available jobsites in list like JBS=Jobsite,LNK=Linked IN ..... so that I can pass this information to users that these are the accessible jobsites for your credentials.

Comment: Do you have the full list of sites?

Comment: no depending upon the login credentials I'll get the job site name and job code. I want to capture these values as code=name (key/ value pair).

Answer (score 0):

Try using [json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/) to deserialize the json into a dynamic object.  Then you should be able to access the properties.

You can also refer to this question: [Deserialize json object into dynamic object using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net)