# Flattening deserialization structure

Tags: .net, json.net, deserialization

I have some JSON that I want to deserialize using Json.Net but I don't want to mimic the JSON object structure. For example I have this order object:

```
{
    "order":
    {
        "order_id": "111-22222222-33",
        "account_identifier": "my account id",
        "customer": "my customer",
        "sku": "WALM-E-500-STD",
        "amount": 500,
        "reward_message": "my message is awesome",
        "reward_subject": "my subject is awesome",
        "reward_from": "me",
        "delivered_at": "2013-11-10T12:49:00+00:00",
        "recipient": {
          "name": "me",
          "email": "my@email.com"
        },
        "reward": {
          "token": "1234567890.1234567890",
          "number": "A1234567890",
          "redemption_url": "http://some.domain.com/r/1234567890"
        }
    }
}
```

I don't want `recipient` or `reward` properties, instead I want to flatten those so that `name`, `email`, `token`, `number`, and `redemption_url` become properties of the order. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this other answer on Stackoverflow: [How to Convert JSON object to Custom C# object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246694/how-to-convert-json-object-to-custom-c-sharp-object)

It shows a way to instantiate an object's properties using JSON.NET in the constructor.  By doing this, you can individually map the data from your structure to the appropriate property in your object.