# Deseralizing JSON in which a value is a JSON string

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, json-deserialization

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2246771/1121302) solution to deserialize my JSON string. I am trying to avoid third-party libraries if at all possible.

However, the string of JSON I'm working with is structured like so:

```
{"BatchId":"32","BatchPriority":"NORMAL","Entries":{"Entry":
    [{"EntryId":"185","EntryPriority":"HIGH","Value":"0.0"},
     {"EntryId":"172","EntryPriority":"LOW","Value":"122.0"}]
}}
```

I am able to deseralize my JSON to set the `BatchId` and `BatchPriority` to the `Batch` object (see below). However, I am unable to set the array of "Entries" from the JSON, whose value appears to be a JSON string itself.

**How do I structure my object such that I am able to deseralize and set the array of "Entries" to the `Batch` object just I am able to set values for the `BatchId` and `BatchPriority` properties?** I know `public Array Entries { get; set; }` is wrong but I am not sure how to approach this.

---

`Batch` object:

```
public class Batch
{
    public int BatchId { get; set; }

    public string BatchPriority { get; set; }

    public Array Entries { get; set; } //wrong
}
```

`Entry` object:

```
public class Entry
{
    public int EntryId { get; set; }

    public string EntryPriority { get; set; }

    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a class that holds a `List<Entry>`

```
public class Entries
{
    public List<Entry> Entry { get; set; }
}
```

If you take a look at [Json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/), it will generate the classes for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your property `public Array Entries { get; set; }` is a `System.Array` called Entries, you want an array or collection of Entry classes called Entry e.g.

```
public class Batch
{
    public int BatchId { get; set; }

    public string BatchPriority { get; set; }

    public Entry[] Entry { get; set; } 
}
```