# Converting json to objects in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have data in the following format. I want to convert this data to objects.

```
 Result = {
 "Location": [
 "bangalore",
  1,
 "chennai",
  1,
 "mumbai",
  1,
 "delhi",
  0,
 "Agra",
  0
 ]
 }
```

In my Location.cs i have the following fields. i want to assign the data to this fields. How can i achieve this

```
public string loc { get; set; }
public int count { get; set; }
```

I tried with

```
 Location = Result.ToObject<List<Location>>();
```

but not working getting the following error

> {"Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Location]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.\r\nPath 'Location'."}

Comment: Please give some more details on what you already did to solve that problem.

Comment: i tried with Result.ToObject<List<Location>>()

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Convert JSON object to Custom C# object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246694/how-to-convert-json-object-to-custom-c-sharp-object)

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/#

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the native json deserializaton that is part of .NET

[MSDN - How to: Serialize and Deserialize JSON Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this: `Result` is a JSON object, not a JSON array, therefore you can't convert it to a `List<Location>`.

You would need a class that contains a list of locations and convert to that class:

```
public class LocationsContainer
{
    public List<Location> Location { get; set; }
}

Result.ToObject<LocationsContainer>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with Json.NET library.

```
List<Location> locations = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Location>>(result);
```

Comment: getting the error The best overloaded method match for 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<System.Collections.Generic.List<TestSolr.Models.Location>>(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: try to change property **count** from _int_ to _string_