# Asp.NET HttpClient with custom JsonConverter

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, json-deserialization

Hi I have the following code to get data from a REST service:

```
HttpResponseMessage response;
                    response = client.GetAsync("CatalogUpdate/" + sessionId).Result;

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        catalogs = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Models.CatalogInfo>>().Result;
                    }
```

My CatalogInfo class is:

```
public class CatalogInfo
    {
        public CatalogInfo(int id,string name,string date)
        {
            this.ID = id;
            this.Name = name;
            this.Date = date;

        }
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }

    }
```

And the jSON that Im getting from the REST service is:

```
{"error":false,"locations":[{"ID":"3","ABC":"XC","Description":"Rome","Status":"1"},{"ID":"4","CD1":"XH","Description":"Italy","Status":"1"}]}
```

I want to map the jSON to my `CatalogInfo` class, is there a way to do this?

Comment: How do you want to *map* considering they have different properties and seem unrelated?

Comment: I want to map ID with ID and Name with Description

Comment: This [question][1] looks similar to what you are looking for.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246694/how-to-convert-json-object-to-custom-c-sharp-object

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option here is to use Json.NET and to create classes that represent the expected JSON, so for example:

```
class Location
{

   public string ID { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
}

class JSONResponse
{

    [JsonProperty("error")]
    public bool Error { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("locations")]
    public Location[] Locations { get; set; }

}
```

We don't have to implement every property as Json.NET will just ignore what isn't there.

Then deserialize the response. In your case you're using `HttpResonseMessage` so something like this:

```
JSONResponse response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONResponse>(
    await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
);
```

You can then use LINQ to convert the locations over to your object:

```
CatalogInfo[] catalog = response.Locations.Select(loc => new CatalogInfo(
    loc.ID,
    loc.Description,
    String.Empty
)).ToArray();
```