# convert json data to strongly typed view

Tags: javascript, c#, json, model-view-controller

i wnat to convert JSON data to model.i tried to serialize by creating class but i am getting error while deserializing

my json data

```
 [{"Name":"Group1","Fields":[{"Field":"EmployeeSCP.Salary","Operator":"lt","Value":"50000","$$hashKey":"object:485"}],"Condition":"0"},
{"Name":"Group2","Fields":[{"Field":"EmployeeSCP.Salary","Operator":"gt","Value":"20000","$$hashKey":"object:495"}],"Condition":"0"},
{"groupCondition":"0"}]
```

model

```
 public class ValidationModelData


{
public string Name { get; set; }
public List<FieldsData> Fields { get; set; }
public string Condition { get; set; }
public string groupCondition { get; set; }
}


public class FieldsData
{
 public string Field { get; set; }
public string Operator { get; set; }
public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

but i am getting error by deserializing

```
 ValidationModelData validations = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ValidationModelData>(validation.JsonMetaData);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246694/how-to-convert-json-object-to-custom-c-sharp-object this one maybe helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I suspected you overlook that it's an array. So you can either put them in array or List like so

```
ValidationModelData[] validations = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ValidationModelData[]>(validation.JsonMetaData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are converting JSON array to C# object. You have to use array or list. I prefer List over array, because  if you want to add/remove `ValidationModelData` then resizing arrays is expensive.

```
List<ValidationModelData> validations = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ValidationModelData>>(validation.JsonMetaData);
```