# MVC - how does model binding work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to convert a string to an object, just like how model binding happens in MVC controllers.
so if I have a string of json like this:

```
{
  "name": "tom",
  "job": "developer",
  "projects": ["projectOne", "projectTwo"]
}
```

I could the convert it to this object:

```
public class Developer
{
  public string name {get; set;}
  public string job {get; set;}
  public string[] projects {get; set;}
}
```

something like this:

```
Developer developer = Convertor.TryConvert<Developer>(myJson);
```

so is there any library or function that can do this?

Comment: You should check : http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: @JonasW could you post an answer so I can make it the right answer?

Comment: I guess I don't understand your question, you've tagged this question with MVC, why not just let MVC model bind it?

Comment: @MohsenShakiba sry for late answer.. I have posted a answer now.

Comment: You do realize that the MVC framework does all this automatically? If the method you posting back to has a parameter `Developer model` then the `model` will be bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check this out : http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Sample :

```
string json = @"{
                   "name": "tom",
                   "job": "developer",
                   "projects": ["projectOne", "projectTwo"]
                 }";

Developer d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Developer>(json);
```

Answer (score 2):

Look here: [How to Convert JSON object to Custom C# object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246694/how-to-convert-json-object-to-custom-c-sharp-object)

Basically one of the answers is:

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Developer user = jss.Deserialize<Developer>(jsonString);
```

Comment: really good answer but sadly I could only choose one correct answer. did vote you up though, thanks a lot