# ListView filled by AutoSuggestBox

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, autosuggest

I would fill a ListView with a AutoSuggestBox. I've already done a AutoSuggestBox that catch items in a json file. How can i put the items in a ListView? 
Thanks

Comment: Language your working in would help most folks to assist you.

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2015 with c# and xaml

Answer (score 0):

If you deserialize the JSON in objects, you can use databinding. Use the ItemsSource property on the ListView control. A  For more information on databinding see [this interesting post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth).
For more information on deserializing JSON to objects, [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246694/how-to-convert-json-object-to-custom-c-sharp-object).

### Martin

If this is an answer to your question, please mark this as answer.