# How to retrieve JsonResult data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following Action in my layouts Controller

```
public JsonResult getlayouts(int lid)
{
    List<layouts> L = new List<layouts>();
    L = db.LAYOUTS.Where(d => d.seating_plane_id == lid).ToList()

    return new JsonResult { Data = L, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

I am calling this Action from another controller like so:

```
layoutsController L = new layoutsController();
JsonResult result = L.getlayouts(lid);
```

My question is: how can I get the data from result object?

Comment: what is the value of result variable?

Comment: i contain the data returnd from the getlayouts() function,wich contain row data from database table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, have a look how you're building the object:

```
new JsonResult { Data = L, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet }
```

You're setting the `L` variable to a property called `Data`. So just read that property:

```
List<layouts> L = (List<layouts>)result.Data;
```

There's nothing special about the fact that it's an MVC controller action.

You're simply calling a method which returns an object that was constructed in the method, and reading properties from that object. Just like any other C# code.

Comment: thank u sir. i m stuck in retriving the jsonresult data.actually i dont know how to itrate json data inside c sharp.

Comment: @rakshi As a suggestion, try converting your Json data to C# objects - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246694/how-to-convert-json-object-to-custom-c-sharp-object

Comment: @rakshi: Why are you using JSON here in the first place?  If you're invoking code directly in the same application, just use your C# objects.  There doesn't seem to be a need for this.

Comment: thank u...i have used the following code and worked for me                      List<layouts> L1 = (List<layouts>)result.Data;
 String lid1 = L1[0].ticket_no_start;
 int lid= Int32.Parse(lid1);

Answer (score 1):

I have my class:

```
public class ResponseJson
{
    public string message { get; set; }
    public bool success { get; set; }
}
```

in my method **SendEmail**

```
private async Task<JsonResult> SendEmailAsync(ApplicationUser user, string returnUrl, string empleadoNombre, string pwdInic)
```

i will return my **JsonResult**

```
ResponseJson response = new ResponseJson();

response.success = true;
response.message = "Operación exitosa";

return new JsonResult( response);
```

to read the result returned from my **SendEmail** method

```
JsonResult emailSend = await SendEmailAsync(user, returnUrl, empleadoNombre, pwdInic);
ResponseJson response = new ResponseJson();
                
try
{ 
      string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emailSend.Value);
      response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseJson>(json);

}
catch(Exception e)
{

}
```

[image: emailSend]

[image: response]