# Ajax send JSON data to a c# model

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I’m new to MVC so I’m not sure if this is the correct way of doing this. What I’m trying to do is send some JSON data to my controller via ajax, then to my model, to eventually do something to it.
The object I’m sending looks like this before I JSON it on the javascript side

```
bannerID:undefined
bannerMode:"WIDGET"
heightSettings:"0"
images:Array[2]
toggleArrows:"true"
toggleIndicators:"true"
transitionSpeed:""
widthSettings:"0"
```

When I JSON it looks like this, when I view it on my controller by replacing widget with string i get this.

```
 {"bannerMode":"WIDGET","transitionSpeed":"","toggleArrows":"true","toggleIndicators":"true","widthSettings":"0","heightSettings":"0","images":

 [{"id":0,"orderRank":"1","imageLink":"http://localhost:49999/img/admin/banner/example.jpg"},{"id":1,"orderRank":"2"}]}
```

In the parameters of the controller of my controller I have a widget model.

```
 public ActionResult Index(widget widgetData){
  return View("~/Views/widgets/_dynamicWidget.cshtml", widgetData);
 }
```

My widget model looks like this.

```
public class widget
 {
    public string bannerMode { get; set; }
    public int transitionSpeed { get; set; }
    public bool toggleArrows { get; set; }
    public bool toggleIndicators { get; set; }
    public int widthSettings = 20;
    private string lang;
    private List<WidgetList> images1;

    public widget(string lang, List<WidgetList> images1)
    {
        this.lang = lang;
        this.images1 = images1;
    }

    public int heightSettings{ get; set; }
    public List<ImageList> images { get; set; }
}

    public class ImageList
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int orderRank { get; set; }
    public string imageLink { get; set; }
}
```

I’m guessing the data should be set into the model ? 
But in my view I’m getting a null error when I try to show this data.

Comment: check your ajax  call url  action and controller correct or not?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking for - are you asking about converting the JSON to a C# class? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246694/how-to-convert-json-object-to-custom-c-sharp-object

Comment: Thanks for your response, the ajax is definitely reaching the controller. When I change the parameters of the controller to "string:widgetData" I can view or the JSON.

Comment: Is that a GET method or a POST method (it will not work with a GET). And your `widget` class has no parameterless constructor so it would throw an exception anyway

Answer (score 1):

Your widget class does not have a public parameterless constructor, so I'm guessing the model binder is failing there.

Comment: Thanks what would you put in the parameters the json data?

Comment: No, you want no parameters on your constructor (or 2 constructors - one without parameters for the model binder and 1 for you to use when you create a new widget in your code).