# Parse json that have uncertain number of data

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

How to parse json that have the Assets object is unknown?

As

```
{   
    "ClassName": "Excel",
    "Teacher": "Esther",
    "Student": 50,
    "Aircond": 0,
    "Assets": {
        "Chair": 50,
        "Table": 50,
        "Fan": 2,
        and might be more here and is unknown to me
    }
}
```

Comment: Here the solution
[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2246724/3301006)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dynamic` as `Assets` type:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public string Teacher { get; set; }
    public int Student { get; set; }
    public int Aircond { get; set; }
    public dynamic Assets { get; set; }
}
```

And then

```
RootObject ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you know for sure that the `Assets` are just a bunch of keys with different kind of values, then you can use an `IDictionary<string, object>` to store the `Assets`:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public string Teacher { get; set; }
    public int Student { get; set; }
    public int Aircond { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, object> Assets { get; set; }
}

var myClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to parse the JSON without creating a custom C# object, you could use [JObject.Parse](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/m_newtonsoft_json_linq_jobject_parse.htm).

```
string json = "{\n\t\"ClassName\": \"Excel\",\n\t\"Teacher\": \"Esther\",\n\t\"Student\": 50,\n\t\"Aircond\": 0,\n\t\"Assets\": {\n\t\t\"Chair\": 50,\n\t\t\"Table\": 50,\n\t\t\"Fan\": 2,\n\t\t\"More\": \"randomText\"\n\t}\n}";
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
Console.WriteLine(jObject["Assets"]["More"]);
```

You will require Newtonsoft.Json which you can install from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/).