# How to parse JSON data in System.Net.Webrequest reponse

Tags: c#, rest, api, webrequest, webresponse

I am trying to call an API which returns the data in JSON format which i need to parse. How to do that in System.Net.Webrequest.. 
Below is my code

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);

            request = WebRequest.Create("https://IPAaddress/api/admin/configuration/v1/conference/1/");

            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
            request.Method = "GET";          

                    // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";          


            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            // Display the status.
            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

            // Display the content.
            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            // Clean up the streams.
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
```

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246694/how-to-convert-json-object-to-custom-c-sharp-object

Comment: Take a look at my article on CodeProject: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233698/Consuming-a-Json-WebService-from-a-Csharp-or-VB-Ap

Comment: Thanks that article is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone my problem got solved, following is the code..

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);

        request = WebRequest.Create("https://ipaddress/api/admin/configuration/v1/conference/1/");

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin", "admin123");
        // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
        request.Method = "GET";          

                // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";          


        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        // Display the status.
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var obj = js.Deserialize<dynamic>(responseFromServer);
        Label1.Text = obj["name"];
        // Display the content.
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
        // Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Webrequest just returns a response from a remote resource. You need to parse the JSON yourself, like using the DataContractJsonSerializer, or Json.Net (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Comment: Do i need to create a data contract class?

Comment: The easiest way is to include the Newtonsoft package in your project: in Package Manager Console, select the project, then run `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json`. Using the data contract types is appropriate when you want to enforce contracts, which may not be what you want.