# How to store JSON data into SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, json

I have a JSON file. In that file around 1000 records. I am using C# and SQL Server.

My requirement is I want to store JSON file's records in to my table which created in SQL Server.

Can anyone tell me how to store JSON data in SQL Server using c# or JavaScript or jQuery anything?

Comment: Check this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dilkushp/2013/10/31/easiest-way-of-loading-json-data-in-sql-using-c/

Comment: What SQL engine are you using?

Comment: sql server 2012

Comment: i suggest you should create an object (or objects) based on your Json and using JSON.NET to convert it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246694/how-to-convert-json-object-to-custom-c-sharp-object#2246724

Comment: Convert JSON to XML and save in SQL 2012 XML DataType. You can parse vice-versa from XML to JSON if needed
Or JSON can be saved as plain text (not recommended).

Answer (score 1):

This questions is a little old but here's an example. If you have SQL Server 2016 you can use a lot of built-in json functions [SQL Server Json Support](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2015/11/23/storing-json-in-sql-server/)

Google newtonsoft json for examples (or whatever library you're using). I'm using the `Newtonsoft.Json` library. Make sure it's referenced in your project or add it via Nuget.

Your class should have a reference to it:

```
  using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Converting C# list of `ChartModel` into json. The model (any POCO works) is defined as:

```
  public class ChartModel
  {
    public string ChartType { get; set; }
    public IList<ChartSeries> Data { get; set; }
    public string ChartTitle { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
  }
```

Convert `List` to its json version:

```
  // Charts = List<ChartModel> 
  var chartJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Charts);

  // or if you want the json formatted
  var chartJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(products, Formatting.Indented);
```

Now you have your json, a string, that can be stored in any `nvarchar` defined column.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by many ways. It depends on your need. if you do it very frequently then

1. Simply upload the file on the server then process a schedule a job
   which processes all the record.
2. Post your file on Server using Jquery then convert it to XML and pass it 
   as a XML parameter to SQL Server procedure and then run insert command. 
   This is not recommended for this type of bulk operation