# Deserialize nested Json String using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hey how do i parse this return Json string. [image]

to get only the Data I tried this approach

Model:

```
public class InstagramProfile
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string bio { get; set; }
    public string website { get; set; }
    public string profile_picture { get; set; }
    public string full_name { get; set; }
    public Counts counts { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
 }
```

for my Service

```
 public class InstagramService
 {
    public async Task<InstagramProfile> GetInstagramProfile(string accessToken)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var userJson = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(Constant.InstagramAu + accessToken);
        var instagramProfile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InstagramProfile>(userJson);
        return instagramProfile;
    }
}
```

To test

```
    private async Task ExcLog()
    {
        var intg = new InstagramService();
        var token = "MyToken";
        var que = await intg.GetInstagramProfile(token);
        await DisplayAlert(PageKeys.Tags, que.full_name, "OK");
    }
```

How do I get the Data?

Comment: Where is the question ? Don't post pictures !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Convert JSON object to Custom C# object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246694/how-to-convert-json-object-to-custom-c-sharp-object)

Comment: @Liam I feel that the accepted answer on the linked duplicate post - while right - is a bit of an antipattern regarding POCO classes. I find it is better to use a service to do the deserialization like OP has demonstrated.

Comment: @MichaelCoxon you should probably point that out on the duplicate if you feel thats true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a model that encompasses the whole JSON object..

```
public class InstagramMeta
{
    public int Code {get;set;}
}

public class InstagramResponse
{
    public InstagramMeta Meta {get;set;}
    public InstagramProfile Data {get;set;}
}
```

You then deserialize on `InstagramResponse`.

If you want to only deserialize the data object - ignore the `Meta` property by removing it from the model.

Comment: Not true, he doesn't care about the metadata, also the names might be case-sensitive.

Comment: @HristoYankov Regardless, my point still stands that they need to use the whole JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

Try generating your model with http://json2csharp.com/
After that you can deserialize your json to a root object. From that you can access the data field and process it.

Comment: Agree, this is how i do it to get the correct model structure.

Answer (score 1):

To build on the awnser from Michael Coxon you can also add the JsonProperty Attribute to map the json names to a property name that you then can rename to what fits your naming convention best:

```
public class InstagramProfile
{
    [JsonProperty("username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("bio")]
    public string Bio { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("website")]
    public string Website { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("profile_picture")]
    public string ProfilePicture { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("full_name")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class SerializedData
{
    public InstagramProfile data { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize to `SerializedData`. Then your data will be in `.data`